# GCD Proof with Multiplication: gcd(ax,bx) = x$\cdot$gcd(a,b)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I was curious as to another method of proof for this:

Given $a$, $b$, and $x$ are all natural numbers,

$\gcd(ax,bx) = x \cdot \gcd(a,b)$

I'm confident I've found the method using a generic common divisor and the theorem that says an integer $C$ is a common divisor of integers $A$ and $B$ iff $C|\gcd(A,B)$.

What other ways can this be proven? Is prime factorization a possibility? Or another method?

Comment: Same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202397

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Below are $3$ proofs of the gcd distributive law $\rm\:(ax,bx) = (a,b)x\:$  using Bezout's identity,  universal gcd laws, and unique factorization.

---

First we show that the gcd distributive law follows immediately from the fact that, by Bezout, the [gcd may be specified by linear equations.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112026/242) Distributivity follows because such linear equations are preserved by scalings. Namely, for naturals $\rm\:a,b,c,x \ne 0$

$\rm\qquad\qquad \phantom{ \iff }\ \ \ \:\! c = (a,b) $

$\rm\qquad\qquad \iff\ \: c\:\ |\ \:a,\:b\ \ \ \  \ \ \&\ \ \ \ c\ =\ na\: +\: kb,\ \  \ $ some $\rm\:n,k\in \mathbb Z$

$\rm\qquad\qquad \iff\  cx\ |\ ax,bx\ \ \ \&\ \ \ cx = nax + kbx,\,\ \ $ some $\rm\:n,k\in \mathbb Z$

$\rm\qquad\qquad { \iff }\ \   cx = (ax,bx) $

The reader familiar with ideals will note that these equivalences are captured more concisely in the distributive law for ideal multiplication $\rm\:(a,b)(x) = (ax,bx),\:$ when interpreted in a PID or Bezout domain, where the ideal $\rm\:(a,b) = (c)\iff c = gcd(a,b)$

---

Alternatively, more generally, in *any* integral domain $\rm\:D\:$ we have

**Theorem** $\rm\ \ (a,b)\ =\ (ax,bx)/x\ \ $ if $\rm\ (ax,bx)\ $ exists in $\rm\:D.$

**Proof** $\rm\quad\: c\ |\ a,b \iff cx\ |\ ax,bx \iff cx\ |\ (ax,bx) \iff c\ |\ (ax,bx)/x\ \ \ $ **QED**

The above proof uses the [*universal* definitions of GCD, LCM](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/if-a-m-and-a-1-m-prove-aa-1-m/3149#3149), which often served to simplify proofs, e.g. see [this proof of the GCD * LCM law.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/upper-and-lower-bounds-of-emptyset/3832#3832)

---

Alternatively, comparing powers of primes in unique  factorizations, it reduces to the following
$$\begin{eqnarray} \min(a+x,\,b+x) &\,=\,& \min(a,b) + x\\
\rm expt\ analog\ of\ \ \ \gcd(a \,* x,\,b \,* x)&=&\rm \gcd(a,b)\,*x\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad\ \ $$

The proof is *precisely* the same as the prior proof, replacing gcd by min, and divides by $\,\le,\,$ and

$$\begin{eqnarray} {\rm employing}\quad\ c\le a,b&\iff& c\le \min(a,b)\\
\rm the\ analog\ of\quad\   c\  \, |\, \ a,b&\iff&\rm c\ \,|\,\ \gcd(a,b) \end{eqnarray}$$

$\ c \le a,b \!\iff\! c\!+\!x \le a\!+\!x,b\!+\!x\!\iff\! c\!+\!x \le \lfloor a\!+\!x,b\!+\!x\rfloor\!\iff\! c \le \lfloor a\!+\!x,b\!+\!x\rfloor \!-\!x$

where $\,\lfloor y,z\rfloor := \min(y,z).$

Comment: @Tim Thanks, and thanks to everyone for the many supportive emails, which played a large role in my decision to return.

Comment: I don't get the last $\Leftrightarrow$ of the first proof with $cx$

Comment: @Maman The first and third equivalences follow by Bezout, i.e. common divisors representable as integral *linear* combinations of the gcd arguments  necessarily are *greatest* common divisors - see the link I gave above the proof.

Answer (score 7):

The following result, sometimes called Bézout's lemma, is usually proved fairly early on in a number theory course,

**Bézout's lemma:** Let $a$ and $b$ be integers, not both $0$. Then $\gcd(a,b)$ is the smallest positive integer which can be expressed in the form  $au+bv$, where $u$ and $v$ are integers.

Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$, and let $w=\gcd(ax,bx)$. Suppose that $x$ is *positive*.

By Bézout's lemma, $w$ is the smallest positive integer which can be expressed in the form $w=(ax)u+(bx)v$. From this last equation, we can see that $x$ divides $w$, so $w=xk$ for some $k$. It follows that $k=au+bv$. We will show $k=d$.

By Bézout's lemma, $d$ is the *smallest* positive integer which can be expressed as an integer linear combination of $a$ and $b$. Since $k=au+bv$, we conclude that $d\le k$.

There are integers $s$ and $t$ such that $as+bt=d$. It follows that $(ax)s+(bx)t=xd$. Since $w=xk$ is the smallest integer that is an integer linear combination of $ax$ and $bx$, we conclude that $xk\le xd$, and therefore $k \le d$.

We have shown that $d \le k$ and $k\le d$. Thus $k=d$, and therefore $\gcd(ax,bx)=x\gcd(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is only true for $x>0$ (some people include $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$).

Here is a proof using prime factorization.
Let
$$
A = \prod p_i^{a_i}
\qquad
\text{and}
\qquad
B = \prod p_i^{b_i}
$$
where the products run over all primes $p_i$
dividing either $A$ or $B$,
which have already been collected and merged.
We can assume this because of the
[fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic),
which guarantees just such a ***unique***
factorization.
To show that
$$
\gcd\left(A,B\right)=\prod p_i^{\min(a_i,b_i)}
$$
$$
\text{lcm}\left(A,B\right)=\prod p_i^{\max(a_i,b_i)}
$$
(where gcd is the *greatest* common divisor),
consider each prime $p_i$ in turn.
Again, we utilize the fact that the gcd and lcm both
have a unique factorization over the integers,
and that they are composed of the same primes
dividing $A$ and $B$, only in different quantities.
The greatest common divisor must have the largest number of $p_i$
common to both $A$ and $B$. These have $a_i$ and $b_i$, respectively.
Therefore the gcd must have the greatest exponent that is common, i.e.
$\max~\{c|c\le a_i,b_i\}=\min(a_i,b_i)$.
Similarly, the exponent of the least common multiple must be the
least integer that is at least as large as both:
$\min~\{c|c\ge a_i,b_i\}=\max(a_i,b_i)$.

There are certain sets of numbers, or number systems,
which [don't have unique factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain#Non-examples), but the integers
(and natural numbers) do, by the FTOA mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry if this seems trivial, but does your statement about gcd and its prime factors offer a formal proof for this? Or is this simply a property of gcd?

Comment: It's not trivial if it's not obvious. Ideas don't think themselves. I added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$. Since $d$ divides both $a$ and $b$, we can write $a=dk$ and $b=dj$.

$\gcd \left({a\over d},{b\over d}\right)=1=\gcd(k,j)$

$xd=\gcd(xdk,xdj)=\gcd(xa,xb)=x\gcd(a,b)$