# $ d = \gcd(a,b)\Rightarrow\ \gcd(a/d,b/d) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Could someone please help me with this proof?

> Suppose that $a, b \in N$, and $d = \gcd(a, b)$. Since $d$ divides $a$, we have $a = de$ for some integer $e,$ and similarly $b = df$ for some integer $f$. Prove that $\gcd(e, f) = 1$.

I understand why it works. Since d is all the common factors of $a$ and $b, e$ and $f$ had no common factors, therefore the $\gcd(e,f) = 1$. But how do I prove this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also: [Proving $\gcd \left(\frac{a}{\gcd (a,b)},\frac{b}{\gcd (a,b)}\right)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/752928) and [Proving that $\gcd\left(\frac a {\gcd(a,b)},\frac b {\gcd(a,b)}\right) =1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/279624).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is  special case of the [gcd **Distributive Law**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242), namely

$$\begin{align} d &= \gcd(de,df)\\[.4em]   
\Longrightarrow\ \  d &= d\gcd(e,f)\ \ \ \text{by the gcd Distributive Law}\\[.4em]  
\smash{\overset{{\rm cancel}\ d}\Longrightarrow}\ \ 1 &=\gcd (e,f)
\end{align}$$

The linked post has proofs of this law (by Bezout, universal property, and prime factorizations).

Comment: this is the best answer,

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\gcd(e,f)\neq 1$. Then $\exists p\in\mathbb P \left(\begin{cases}p\mid e\\p\mid f\end{cases}\right)$ and so $\begin{cases}dp\mid de=a\\dp\mid df=b\end{cases}$, contradiction.

Comment: very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have the key idea of the proof. The challenge is now to make it rigorous.

Suppose that $e$ and $f$ have a common factor, $D$. We want to show that $D$ is already "included" in $d$.

From the two equations you wrote down, we have $Dd\mid a,b$. What does this tell you about $D$?

Comment: it would say that d = Dd, which cannot be true. if d is really the gcd(a,b)

Comment: @DanielD'Souza or unless $D=1$