# Show that two numbers divided by their GCD are coprime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ and $d = \gcd(a, b)$. Show that $gcd(\frac{a}{d}, \frac{b}{d}) = 1$.

I tried proving this by contradiction and showing that otherwise $d$ isn't the gcd of $a$ and $b$, but it didn't work. Could someone please give me a hint on what the proof should look like?

Comment: "It didn't work"... Can you elaborate?  This sounds like you took the perfect approach...

Comment: See also: [Proving $\gcd \left(\frac{a}{\gcd (a,b)},\frac{b}{\gcd (a,b)}\right)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/752928) and [Proving that $\gcd\left(\frac a {\gcd(a,b)},\frac b {\gcd(a,b)}\right) =1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/279624).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $d'>1$ divides both $\frac{a}{d}$ and $\frac{b}{d}$ then $dd'> d$ divides $a$ and $b$, contradicting the fact that $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thanks, this inequality is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Recall Bezout's identity and the definition of greatest common divisior that comes along with it.

If $(a,b)=d$ then there are integers $u$ and $v$ such that $$ au + bv = d$$

What happens when you divide $a$ and $b$ by $d$?

Alternatively, if you prefer, just use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic and see with your own eyes they have no common divisor.