# Find three distinct positive integers $x,y,z$ such that $15xyz=\text{lcm}(x,y,z)\cdot \gcd(x,y,z)$

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

> Find three distinct positive integers $x,y,z$ such that $xyz=\text15\cdot{lcm}(x,y,z)\cdot \gcd(x,y,z)$

I've proved this for two numbers $x$ and $y$, but I'm not sure how to expand this to three numbers or even to $n$ numbers

Comment: This may help somewhat: [GCD to LCM of multiple numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319297/gcd-to-lcm-of-multiple-numbers)

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Can you solve the problem with $3$ instead of $15$? (Hint: you can do so using only powers of $3$.) What about $5$ instead of $15$? Can you combine those two solutions somehow?

Comment: Is coefficient $15$ at the LHS? not in the RHS? Simply, if $x=\prod_j p_j^{a_j}, y =\prod_j p_j^{b_j}, z=\prod_j p_j^{c_j}$, then $$lcm(x,y,z)=\prod p_j^{\max\{a_j,b_j,c_j\}},$$ $$gcd(x,y,z)=\prod p_j^{\min\{a_j,b_j,c_j\}},$$ and $$\max\{a,b,c\}+\min\{a,b,c\}\le a+b+c$$ for non-negative $a,b,c$.

Comment: @Oleg567 It is on left hand side... And can you simplify the symbols down a bit? I'm in 7th grade lol

Comment: Then there are no solutions, since $$xyz\ge gcd(x,y,z)\cdot lcm(x,y,z).$$

Comment: @Oleg567 Should add that as answer maybe, and can you prove that 15xyz is greater than gcd(x,y,z)*lcm(x,y,z)?

Comment: Ok, I'll try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider example, which will show that $xyz\ge lcm(x,y,z)\cdot gcm(x,y,z)$
.

Let $x=24$, $y=50$, $z=70$.

Then consider prime factorization of these numbers:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
number & 2 & 3 & 5 &  7 \\ \hline
x & 2^3 & 3 & - & - \\
y & 2 & - & 5^2 & - \\
x & 2 & - & 5 & 7 \\ \hline
gcd(x,y,z) & 2 & - & - & - \\ \hline 
lcm(x,y,z) & 2^3 & 3 & 5^2 &7 \\ \hline 
xyz & 2^3\cdot 2 \cdot 2 & 3 &  5^2\cdot 5 & 7 \\ \hline
\end{array}

GCD collects smallest powers of each prime.

LCM collects largest powers of each prime.

So, if consider any prime number $p$, then

$$x = p^a \cdot x_1,$$
$$y = p^b \cdot y_1,$$
$$z = p^c \cdot z_1,$$
where $a\ge 0, b\ge 0, c\ge 0$; then
$$gcd(x,y,z) = p^{\min\{a,b,c\}}g_1;$$
$$lcm(x,y,z) = p^{\max\{a,b,c\}}l_1;$$
$$xyz = p^{a+b+c}m_1,$$
where $x_1,y_1,z_1$, $g_1$, $l_1$ and $m_1$ are not divisible by $p$.

But $a+b+c\ge \min\{a,b,c\}+\max\{a+b+c\}$.
Since $a+b+c = \min\{a,b,c\}+medium\{a,b,c\}+\max\{a,b,c\}.$

And such property $-$ for each prime number from the table.

---

If $15$ would be on RHS, then one can construct such $(x,y,z)$: $(3,5,15)$, $(5,15,30)$ for example.

How to find such triples?
Let $$x=2^{a_1}\cdot 3^{a_2}\cdot 5^{a_3}\cdot 7^{a_4}\cdot \ldots;$$
 $$y=2^{b_1}\cdot 3^{b_2}\cdot 5^{b_3}\cdot 7^{b_4}\cdot \ldots;$$
 $$z=2^{c_1}\cdot 3^{c_2}\cdot 5^{c_3}\cdot 7^{c_4}\cdot \ldots;$$
where $a_1,b_1,...,c_4, ...$ $-$ all numbers are non-negative integer numbers.

Then
$$xyz = 2^{a_1+b_1+c_1}\cdot 3^{a_2+b_2+c_2}\cdot 5^{a_3+b_3+c_3}\cdot 7^{a_4+b_4+c_4}\cdot \ldots;$$
$$
gcd(x,y,z)\cdot lcm(x,y,z) =  2^{\min\{a_1,b_1,c_1\}+\max\{a_1,b_1,c_1\}}\\ \times
3^{\min\{a_2,b_2,c_2\}+\max\{a_2,b_2,c_2\}}\\ \times
5^{\min\{a_3,b_3,c_3\}+\max\{a_3,b_3,c_3\}}\\ \times
7^{\min\{a_4,b_4,c_4\}+\max\{a_4,b_4,c_4\}}\\ \times \ldots;
$$
Since there is $15=3\cdot 5$ near $gcd\cdot lcm$, then looking at powers of $2$, then at powers of $3$ etc, we conclude:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
a_1+b_1+c_1 = \min\{a_1,b_1,c_1\} + \max\{a_1,b_1,c_1\}; \\
a_2+b_2+c_2 = \min\{a_2,b_2,c_2\} + \max\{a_2,b_2,c_2\} \large{+ 1}; \\
a_3+b_3+c_3 = \min\{a_3,b_3,c_3\} + \max\{a_3,b_3,c_3\} \large{+ 1}; \\
a_4+b_4+c_4 = \min\{a_4,b_4,c_4\} + \max\{a_4,b_4,c_4\}; \\
\ldots
\end{array}
\right.
$$
from this point we conclude that:

- medium number of $a_1,b_1,c_1$ is $0$ (then the smallest is $0$ too);
- medium number of $a_2,b_2,c_2$ is $1$ (then the smallest is $0$  or $1$);
- medium number of $a_3,b_3,c_3$ is $1$ (then the smallest is $0$ or $1$);
- medium number of $a_4,b_4,c_4$ is $0$ (then the smallest is $0$ too);
- ...

Let us construct such sets of powers:

$a_1=0,b_1=3,c_1=0$; (smallest is $0$, **medium is** $0$, largest is $3$)
$a_2=1,b_2=2,c_2=0$; (smallest is $0$, **medium is** $1$, largest is $2$)
$a_3=2,b_3=1,c_3=1$; (smallest is $1$, **medium is** $1$, largest is $2$)
$a_4=1,b_4=0,c_4=0$; (smallest is $0$, **medium is** $0$, largest is $1$)
and let other primes have powers $0$ (for simplicity);

and finally compose $x,y,z$:

$x=2^{a_1}\cdot 3^{a_2}\cdot 5^{a_3}\cdot 7^{a_4} = 2^0\cdot 3^1\cdot 5^2\cdot 7^1 = 525$;

$y=2^{b_1}\cdot 3^{b_2}\cdot 5^{b_3}\cdot 7^{b_4} = 2^3\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^1\cdot 7^0 = 360$;

$z=2^{c_1}\cdot 3^{c_2}\cdot 5^{c_3}\cdot 7^{c_4} = 2^0\cdot 3^0\cdot 5^1\cdot 7^0 = 5$;

$gcd(x,y,z) = 5$, $lcm(x,y,z)=12\:600$, $xyz=945\:000$,
$945\:000 = 15\cdot 5 \cdot 12\:600$.

Just for training: reproduce this construction for getting triple $x=3,y=5,z=15$, or other one: $x=5,y=15,z=30$.

Comment: What do the g1, l1, and m1 mean? and by medium do you mean the median?

Comment: $g_1$ is part of $gcd(...)$-factorization  which is not divisible by $p$; in fact, $g_1 = gcd(x_1,y_1,z_1)$. $l_1 -$ similar. For this example, and for $p=2$ we'll have $g_1=1$, $l_1=3\cdot 5^2\cdot  7$.

Comment: wait up the 15 is on rhs sry my teacher made typo. Proof for that?

Comment: @Gerard, I updated answer with description of solution construction.