# Ternary generalizations of $\,\gcd(n,m)\,{\rm lcm}(n,m) = nm$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

$\gcd(n,m)\,{\rm lcm}(n,m) = nm.\,$ Can this theorem work with 3 integers? And how to prove it? I tried doing this with 2 integers n,m , but I can't figure out how to do it with 3.

Comment: $abc=a(bc)$. What are DBD and MBK?

Comment: Oh sorry, Im not native english speaker so I miswrote them, DBD is GCD and MBK is LCM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[From here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319297/gcd-to-lcm-of-multiple-numbers/319690#319690):*

We have that

**Theorem:** $\rm\ \ lcm(a,b,c)\, =\, \dfrac{abc}{(bc,ca,ab)}$

**Proof:** $\!\begin{align}\qquad\qquad\rm\ a,b,c&\mid\rm\ k\\ 
\iff\quad\rm abc&\mid \rm\,\ kbc,kca,kab\\ 
\iff\quad\rm abc&\mid \rm (kbc,kca,kab)\, =\, k(bc,ca,ab)\\  
\iff\rm \ \dfrac{abc}{(bc,ca,ab)} &\:\Bigg| \rm\,\ k\end{align}$

where $(bc, ca, ab) $ means the gcd of $ab, bc, ca $. Hope it helps.

Comment: As a courtesy, when you quote verbatim [an answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/319690/242) posted by another user, you should cite that answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes, yes, very sorry. In fact I was then going to cite that answer, but due to unavoidable circumstances, totally forgot about it. Will never do it again. Very sorry once again.

Comment: No problem, I presumed it was an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

Let the highest power of prime $p$ that divides $a,b,c$ be $A,B,C$  respectively.

So, the highest power of prime $p$ that divides the GCD will be min$(A,B,C)$

and the highest power of prime $p$ that divides the LCM will be max$(A,B,C)$

We need  min$(A,B,C)+$max$(A,B,C)=A+B+C$ for any prime that divides at least one of $a,b,c$

WLOG  min$(A,B,C)=A,$ and max$(A,B,C)=C\implies A+C=A+B+C\iff B=0$

So, $(a,b,c)$ must be $1$ for LCM$(a,b,c)\cdot$GCD$(a,b,c)=abc$

For the two integer case,  trivially min$(A,B)+$max$(A,B)=A+B$