# Prove $\text{lcm}(x,y)/\text{gcd}(x,y) \in N$

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

Prove that $$\frac{\text{lcm}(x,y)}{\text{gcd}(x,y)}\in\Bbb N$$
for all $x, y \in \Bbb N$. And what kind of conditions you need, so  $\frac{\text{lcm}(x,y)}{\text{gcd}(x,y)}$ would be equal integer's square?

Comment: We can follow the pattern from  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120744/gcd-and-lcm-theorem/2120753#2120753

Comment: I think the solution becomes obvious once you see that $LCM(x,y)=p_1^{\max(x_1,y_1)}p_2^{\max (x_2,y_2)}...p_n^{\max(x_n,y_n)}$
and $GCD(x,y)=p_1^{\min(x_1,y_1)}p_1^{\min(x_n,y_n)}...p_n^{\min(x_n,y_n)}$
where $p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}..p_n^{x_n}$ is the prime factorization of x and $p_1^{y_1}p_2^{y_2}..p_n^{y_n}$ is the prime factorization of y

Comment: Do you realize this question is the same thing as asking you to prove $\gcd(x,y) \mid \operatorname{lcm}(x,y)$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\ d\mid x\mid m\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid m\,$ by *transitivity* of divisibility.

As for the second question, note that a positive integer is a square iff every prime occurs to even power in its unique prime factorization. But the power of a prime $p$ in the lcm/gcd is even iff its power in $x$ and $y$ have equal parity (since it's their max $-$ min in lcm/gcd). This is equivalent to $x/y$ being a square of a rational, or $xy$ being a square.

Comment: i.e. by [gcd & lcm universal property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3356212/242) $\,\gcd(a,b)\mid a\mid {\rm lcm}(a,b)\,$ so the claim follows by *transitivity* of divisibility.

It boils down to $\,\inf S \le \sup S\,$ in poset / lattice language. More generally, the hint shows that *every* common divisor of a set of integers divides *every* common multiple.