# How to yield lcm between several numbers?

Tags: least-common-multiple

How to find LCM between several numbers? For example, how to find LCM between the numbers 7, 24, 3 and 10?

Comment: Take the lcm of the first two. Take the lcm of that with the third number, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definition:** The least common multiple LCM of two or more numbers is the least number which is divisible by each of them without remainder.

---

For finding LCM, prime factorization might help! The lcm will be the product of multiplying the highest power of each prime number together.

$$7=7\\24=3 \times 2^3 \\3=3\\10=2 \times 5$$

So $$\text{lcm}\{7,24,3,10\}=7 \times 2^3 \times3 \times 5=840$$

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE! If the lcm between two numbers $a$ and $b$ is denoted by $[a,b]$, then for three numbers $a,b,c$, $[a,b,c]=[[a,b],c]$, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

$$LCM(a,b)=\frac {a\cdot b}{GCD(a,b)}$$
But, $$LCM(a,b,c)\neq\frac {a\cdot b \cdot c}{GCD(a,b,c)}$$
So, the best way is to take partial LCMs, until you reach the last number, following an algorithm: $$LCM(a,b,c,...)=LCM (LCM(a,b),c,...)$$

For $7,24,3$ and $10$:
Select any $2$ numbers randomly (or the way you feel it will be easier) $$LCM(7,3)=21$$ $$LCM(21,10)=210$$ 
$$LCM(24,210)=\frac {24 \cdot 210}{GCD(24,210)}$$ $$=\frac{24\cdot 210}{6}$$

> $$LCM(3,7,10,24)=840$$

Comment: $$LCM(a,b,c)=\frac{a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot GCD(a,b,c)}{GCD(a,b)\cdot GCD(a,c)\cdot GCD(b,c)}$$

Comment: @bof looks good! can it be generalized?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319297/gcd-to-lcm-of-multiple-numbers/1213619#1213619