# A sufficient condition for the formula $\frac{a_1 \cdots a_n}{gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n)} = lcm(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$

Tags: number-theory

> I am trying to find a sufficient condition so that
>
> $$\frac{a_1 \cdots a_n}{gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n)} = lcm(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$$
>
> holds.

My idea would be to require that $gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n) = 1$, i.e. the $a_i$ are pairwise coprime, which is clearly a necessary condition.

However, I am having trouble proving that $gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n) = 1$ is indeed also sufficient. I tried to start by assuming that

$$\frac{a_1 \cdots a_n}{gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n)} = lcm(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$$

holds, but I do not see how I can conlcude from there that $gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n) = 1$. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: First try $n=3$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319297/gcd-to-lcm-of-multiple-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the statement is true for $n = 2$, henceforth we focus on $ n \geq 3$.

Note: $ \gcd (a_i) = 1 $ is not a sufficient condition, which might explain why you're having trouble proving a false statement.

Find a counter example.

---

**Hint:** If $ a_i = \prod {p_k} ^ {i_k}$, then $\gcd(a_i) = \prod p_k ^ { \min i_k } , lcm (a_i) = \prod p_k ^ { \max i_k } $.

So, for the equation to hold, we must have for every prime $p_k$.

$$ \sum i_k = \min i_k  + \max i_k $$

When can this hold?

> Show that for each $p_k$, at most one $i_k$ is non-zero.

Thus, what is the necessary and sufficient condition?

> Each prime $p_k$ divides at most one $a_i$.

If you're stuck even after reading the hints, show your work and what you've tried.

Comment: The argument is incorrect. Your claim is sufficient but not necessary (e.g. it is true for all $a_i$ when $n = 2)\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes indeed. I made the implicit assumption that $ n \geq 3$. Let me add that in.