# How to prove $\left(\frac{a}{(a,b)}, \frac{b}{(a,b)}\right) = 1$?

Tags: number-theory

I have a number theory question that has me stumped.

Let $a, b, c \in \Bbb Z$ with $a$ and $b$ both not zero. Prove:
$(\frac{a}{(a,b)}, \frac{b}{(a,b)}) = 1$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $(k a, k b) = k (a, b)$

Comment: What do you know? An answer will depend on what stage you’re at in number theory.

Comment: Please make titles more *informative*. See what I changed it to, so you can do something similar next time.

Comment: Where is $c$ used?

Comment: It is the speed of light, rounded down...

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone! Mr. Tamaroff, I'll use that in the future!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202397

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@vonbrand's comment is the most succinct answer. Here is a more verbose approach:

Let $d =\gcd(a,b)$. Let $l = \gcd(\frac{a}{d}, \frac{b}{d})$. Then $l \mid \frac{a}{d}$, $l \mid \frac{b}{d}$, which implies $ld \mid a$, $ld \mid b$. Hence $ld \le d$, from which we get $l \le 1$. Since  $1 \mid a$, $1 \mid b$, we have $1 \le l$. So $l=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Bezout's identity will give you the answer immediately: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

It tells us that there exist integers $x,y$ such that $$xa+yb=(a,b).$$Divided by $(a,b)$ gives $x\frac{a}{(a,b)}+y\frac{b}{(a,b)}=1$, and note that the GCD of $\frac{a}{(a,b)}$ and $\frac{b}{(a,b)}$ must divide the RHS.

Answer (score 1):

$$ax+by=(a,b)$$ has a solution. Divide by $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply the special case $\: c = (a,b)\:$ of the $\,$ *gcd distributive law* $\ (a/c,b/c) = (a,b)/c$

[See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/113045/23500) for a few proofs of distributivity (by linearity (Bezout); universality; prime factorization).