# Proving that if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then $\gcd(a, c) = \gcd(a,bc)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How to prove that if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, then $\gcd(a, c) = \gcd(ab,c)$?

How to make a connection between $(a,b)=1$ and $ab$? I have no idea.

Comment: Hmm...are you missing some hypotheses? Take $a=2$, $b=3$ and $c=3$.

Comment: You mean $\rm\:b,c\:$ coprime, or else you mean $\rm\:gcd(a,bc).\:$ My answer assumes the latter (swap $\rm\:a\:$ and $\rm\:c\:$ in my answer if you meant the former).

Answer (score 4):

I presume the problem is $\rm\: \color{#C00}{(a,b)=1}\:\Rightarrow\: (a,bc) = (a,c),\:$ where $\rm\:(x,y) := gcd(x,y).\:$ One quick proof uses basic gcd laws: $\rm\,\ (a,bc) = (a,bc,ac) =  (a,(bc,ac)) = (a,\color{#C00}{(b,a)}c) = (a,c)$.

Alternatively: if $\rm\:d\mid a\:$ then $\rm\:d\mid bc\iff d\mid bc,ac\iff d\mid (bc,ac)=\color{#C00}{(b,a)}c = c.\:$ So $\rm\:a,bc\:$ and $\rm\:a,c\:$ have equal sets $\rm\,D\,$ of *common divisors* $\rm\:d,\:$ so equal *greatest* common divisor (= max $\rm\,D$).

**Remark** $\ $ If desired, one can trade gcd laws for Bezout identities, e.g

$$\rm\:(a,b)=1\:\Rightarrow\:\exists\, j,k\in\Bbb Z\!:\ ja\!+\!kb=1\ \ \ so\ \ \ d\mid a,bc\:\Rightarrow\: d\mid (ja\!+\!kb)c = c\qquad $$

which trades the above use of the [gcd distributive law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/113045/23500) for said Bezout identity. However, the proofs using the gcd laws work more generally (general gcd domains need not have linear (Bezout) gcds).

Answer (score 2):

Probably you mean $\gcd(a,c)=\gcd(a,bc)$. Here is a different solution from that of Math Gems.

The $\gcd(a,b)$ can be characterized as the minimum of the set $N_{a,b}=\{ax+by\in\mathbb N:x,y\in\mathbb Z\}$. Since $\gcd(a,b)=1\Rightarrow ax+by=1$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb Z$.
Now if $aw+bcz\in N_{a,bc}\Rightarrow aw+bcz\in N_{a,c}$ right?
Conversely if $as+ct=q\in N_{a,c}$ then multiplying with $ax+by=1$ we obtain $a(asx+bsy+ctx)+bcty=q$ therefore $as+ct=q=a(asx+bsy+ctx)+bcty\in N_{a,bc}$.
We conclude that $N_{a,c}=N_{a,bc}$ and therefore $\gcd(a,c)=\min N_{a,c}=\min N_{a,bc}=\gcd(a,bc)$.