# GCD of polynomials over GF(p)

Tags: number-theory

I have two polynomials:
$$
f(x)=(x^2+1)(x-2)
$$
$$
g(x)=(x^3+7)(x-2)  
$$
I am supposed to find their GCD over GF(p) for some prime p.
I "understand" that their GCD is $(x-2)$ but what is the meaning to find the GCD over $GF(2)$ or $GF(3)$?
I know that $(x-2) \equiv x \pmod 2$, so the GCD(f,g) over GF(2) is $x$?
Am I right? wrong? Am I getting anywhere?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often things turn up in mathematics to have a natural [ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set). In particular, when it comes to divisibility in commutative rings, we can say that "$\rm n$ is bigger than $\rm d$" if $\rm d\mid n$ (that is, if there exists some $\rm k\in R$ such that $\rm n=dk$). Given two elements $\rm a,b$ in a ring $\rm R$, we say $\rm d$ is a *common divisor* if it is a divisor of both, i.e. $\rm d\mid a$ and $\rm d\mid b$. Then we say $\rm c$ is a [**gcd**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#The_gcd_in_commutative_rings) of $\rm a$ and $\rm b$ if it's uniquely maximal among the set of common divisors - that is, if $\rm c$ is itself a common divisor of $\rm a,b$, and every other common divisor $\rm d$ of $\rm a,b$ divides $\rm c$ as well (i.e. $\rm d\mid a,b\implies d\mid c$).

The gcd is generally only defined up to multiplication by arbitrary unit $\rm u\in R^\times$. In the context of polynomial rings, $\rm K[x]$ where $\rm K$ is a field, of all of the gcds we choose the *monic* one so that the gcd is a well-defined function (spits out only one output for any set of inputs). In addition, for this setting we have a nice [*Euclidean algorithm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) (which is used explicitly below) that makes hand computations feasible, pleasant even.

See the [Wikipedia page on polynomial gcds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#The_gcd_in_commutative_rings) for more information. To summarize the Euclidean algorithm for computing gcds as succinctly as possible, I'd say this: add/subtract multiples of one argument to the other repeatedly in order to simply the expression - in particular, to reduce the degree of the polynomial in one or the other argument at each stage. Notice how in the integer setting the algorithm seeks to reduce the *size* of the arguments at each stage, whereas in the polynomial setting the algorithm seeks to reduce the *degrees*. The analogy between the absolute values of integers and degrees of polynomials runs surprisingly deep into number theory.

One useful trick is $\rm \gcd(an,am)=a\gcd(n,m)$. This allows you to reduce the problem via

$$\rm \gcd(f(x),g(x))=(x-2)\gcd(\color{Blue}{x^2+1},\color{Purple}{x^3+7})$$
$$\rm =(x-2)\gcd(\color{Blue}{x^2+1},\color{Purple}{x^3+7}-\color{DarkOrange}{x}(\color{Blue}{x^2+1}))=(x-2)\gcd(\color{Teal}{x^2+1},\color{Purple}{7-x})$$
$$\rm =(x-2)\gcd(\color{Teal}{x^2+1}+\color{Red}{x}(\color{Purple}{7-x}),7-x)=(x-2)\gcd(7x+1,7-x)$$

using the rules $\rm \gcd(\color{Blue}{a},\color{Purple}{b})=\gcd(\color{Blue}{a},\color{Purple}{b}\pm\color{DarkOrange}{n}\color{Blue}{a})$ and $\rm \gcd(\color{Teal}{a},\color{Purple}{b})=\gcd(\color{Teal}{a}\pm \color{Red}{m}\color{Purple}{b},\color{Purple}{b})$ (for arbitrary choices of $\rm \color{DarkOrange}{n},\color{Red}{m}\in K[x]$) repeatedly. Notice the above computation is valid *in any field*. Specializing to ${\bf F}_2$ aka $GF(2)$ ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field)), $\color{Purple}{7}=\color{Purple}{1}$ and $\color{Teal}{2}=\color{Teal}{0}$ and $\color{Blue}{-1}=\color{Blue}{1}$ so the computation may be finished as

$$\rm (x-\color{Teal}{2})\gcd(\color{Purple}{7}x+1,\color{Purple}{7}\color{Blue}{-}x)=x\gcd(x+1,1\color{Blue}{+}x)=x(x+1).$$

Comment: Why this $(x−2)gcd(x^2+1,x^3+7−x(x^2+1))$? How did it come to your mind?

Comment: @bomba6 It's the idea behind the Euclidean algorithm, which I edited in a few words about just now. Recall in the integer setting, if you want to compute say $\gcd(100,23)$ using EA, you'd write $100=23\cdot4+8$ via the [division algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm), so that you may write $$\gcd(100,23)=\gcd(100-4\cdot23,23)=\gcd(8,23).$$ Similarly $23=4\cdot8-1$ so $$\gcd(8,23)=\gcd(8,23-4\cdot8)=\gcd(8,-1)=1.$$ In the polynomial setting, to do the same, at each stage ask "what can I multiply one argument by and add/subtract to the other in order to *reduce degrees*?"

Comment: Continuing your example for GF(5), and the fact that 7=4(3), -1=2(3) and 1=-2(3) I get $2(x-2)gcd(x+2,x-2)$, but again, I'm stuck.

Comment: @bomba6 If you're going mod 3 then you're talking about GF(3) rather than GF(5). In this case (first of all ignore the 2 out in front; remember we want monic so we can ignore all scalar multiples of the entire expression by invertible elements), note that mod 3 we have -2=1 and 7=1 so $$\rm (x-2)\gcd(7x+1,7-x)=(x+1)\gcd(x+1,2x+1)$$ $$\rm =(x+1)\gcd(x+1,2x+1-(x+1))=(x+1)\gcd(x+1,x)=x+1.$$

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that... Lets see were I'm heading. Thanks for your help. (and I meat GF(3) indeed.

Answer (score 3):

It means what it literally says; $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are given as polynomials with coefficients in, say, $\mathbf{F}_5$. (any polynomial with coefficients in the integers can easily be converted to such a polynomial) Then, you compute their polynomial $\gcd$.

And the $\gcd$ might not be $x-2$. Continuing with the $\mathbf{F}_5$ example, it turns out that their $\gcd$ is $(x-2)^2$, because

$$ (x^2 + 1) = (x-2)(x-3) $$
$$ (x^3 + 7) = (x-2)(x^2 + 2x + 4) $$

and $x^2 + 2x + 4$ is relatively prime to $x-3$. But rather than factoring, the $\gcd$ can be easily computed by using the Euclidean algorithm.

Of course, $(x-2)^2 = (x+3)^2 = (x-2)(x+3)$, so any of those could be given as the $\gcd$.

---

One might be interested in the more sophisticated question of, given those two polynomials with coefficients in the integers, for which values of $p$ their $\gcd$ be $(x-2)$ after converting them into polynomials over $\mathbf{F}_p$.

The answer to this question can be solved with resultants; as polynomials over the integers, we have

$$ \text{Res}(x^2 + 1, x^3 + 7) = 50 $$

which tells us that these two polynomials will be relatively prime (after converting them into polynomials over $\mathbf{F}_p$) if and only if $p$ is relatively prime to $50$.

In particular, this means you need to rethink your statement of the $\gcd$ in the case of $p=2$!

(note that $\text{Res}(f(x), g(x)) = 0$ which tells us that $f$ and $g$ aren't even relatively prime over the rational numbers!)

Comment: What I'm missing is, probably, the notion that $(x^3+7)=(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)$ in GF(5)... I wonder how to calculate this. Plus- what do you mean calculating the GCD using the Euclidean algorithm? I have used this method go get my "original" $x-2$ answer... (f,g were not factored in the first place).

Comment: @bomba6 You don't need to compute such factorizations - see my answer. Please feel welcome to ask questions if anything is not clear.

Comment: @bomba6: Then either you made a mistake in the Euclidean algorithm, or more likely you computed the GCD by doing arithmetic in $\mathbb{Q}$ when you should have been doing it with arithmetic in $\mathbf{F}_2$. Did you ever divide by $2$ in your calculation? That's a sure sign that you were doing arithmetic in the wrong field. (because you *can't* divide by $2$ in $\mathbf{F}_2$... because $2=0$ and you can't divide by $0$)

Comment: @Hurkyl I need to compute the GCD over GF(p) for all primes < 31. I think I not supposed to run the entire algorithm so many times.

Comment: @bomba6: If you don't use my resultant trick, then what you can do is proceed by using only steps that work in *every* field. Then, when you want to do something special (like divide by $2$), then you can split the problem into two cases: one where you find it in $\mathbf{F}_2$, and one where division by $2$ is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $ $  Use Euclid's algorithm $\rm\ gcd(a,b) = gcd(a,b\ {\bf mod}\ a)\ $
and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/113045) $\rm\:gcd(ca,cb) = c\,gcd(a,b)$
$$\rm\quad (x\!-\!2)\,gcd(\color{}{x^2\!+\!1},\,7\!+\!\color{#c00}{x^3})\, =\, (x-2)\,gcd(\color{#0a0}{x^2}\!+\!1,\,7\!\color{#c00}{-\!x})\, =\, (x\!-\!2)\,gcd(\color{#0a0}{7^2}\!+\!1,\,7\!-\!x)$$

where we used $\rm\:{\bf mod}\ \ \color{}{ x^2\!+1}\!:\ x^2\!\equiv -1\, \Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{x^3\!\equiv -x};\: $  $\rm\:{\bf mod}\ \ 7\!-\!x\!:\ x\equiv 7\:\Rightarrow\:\color{#0a0}{x^2\!\equiv 7^2}$

**Remark** $\ \rm{GF}(p) = \Bbb F_p\:$ denotes the finite field of $\rm\:p\:$ elements. The Euclidean algorithm works for polynomials over any field, in the same way as it does over the classical fields, because polynomial long division-with-remainder algorithm works *universally* for polynomials that are *monic* (i.e. lead coefficient $= 1$). But, over a field, every polynomial is associate to a monic polynomial (multiply it by the inverse of the leading coefficient).

Comment: @Math Gems- I am a slow reader. Plus, my reputation is not letting me to vote up. I'm reading, still trying to figure out the best way to do it, without the trick of $(x-2)gcd(...)$ because we haven't learned this way.

Comment: @bomba6 You don't know that $\rm\:gcd(ca,cb)\, =\, c\,gcd(a,b)\,?\ $  This is the gcd *distributive law*. $\ $

Comment: @bomba6 [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/113045) has three proofs of the gcd distributive law - all of which work also for polynomials over a field.

Comment: @MathGems yes, my mistake... haven't noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

Hurkyl said:

Res(x2+1,x3+7)=50
which tells us that these two polynomials will be relatively prime (after converting them into polynomials over Fp) iff p is relatively prime to 50.

Could someone point me to a proof of said statement? Obviously for the general case not just this specific one..

Comment: This should not be posted as an answer to the initial question.

Comment: This should be asked as its own question: that way people can find it and benefit from the answer as well.

Comment: Yeah realized that after posting. Made a new question for that. Thx for the advice.