# Divisibility property: $\gcd(a,b)=1,\, a,b\mid c\Rightarrow ab\mid c$

Tags: number-theory

suppose $a|c$ , $b|c$ and $gcd(a,b)=1$ .Then show that $ab|c$. Here $a,b,c$ are all real numbers.Can i start from the properties of divisibility as if $a|c$ and $c|b$ then $a|b$?

Comment: The proof requires more than general divisibility properties. What else do you know, Euclid'd Lemma, or Bezout's Identity for the gcd, or the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (existence and uniqueness of prime factorizations)?

Comment: *Real* numbers?? Are you sure?

Comment: i think it should be integers

Answer (score 2):

If $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$, then $ab\mid bc$ and $ab\mid ac$, so
$$ab\mid\gcd(ac,bc)=c\gcd(a,b)=c$$

Comment: Remark that this implicitly uses uses the GCD *distributive law*, which can be replaced by Bezout if desired - see proofs 2 and 3 in my answer, and follow the link there for further exposition.

Comment: Or see the previous versions of my post where I proved the required direction. I edited it out for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You mean integers.

$a|c$ means $c = ak$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Thus $b|c$ can be rewritten as $b|ka$, but $gcd(a,b)=1$ so $b|k$ which in turn means $k=lb$ for some $l \in \mathbb{N}$.

Finally $c = lba$, so $ab|c$.

Comment: Remark that the proof implicitly invokes Euclid's Lemma (or unique factorization) to deduce that $\,b\mid k.\,$ This is the same as proof 1 in my answer, with $\ k\,:=\,c/b.\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

Since gcd $(a,b)=1$ hence $\exists x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ax+by=1$. Thus, $acx+bcy=c$. Now $ab$ divides LHS (why ?) and hence $ab |c$.

Comment: Remark that the proof invokes Bezout's Identity for the gcd, which could be replaced by the GCD distributive law if so desired. See proofs 2 and 3 in my answer, where I align both versions to highlight the analogy between the two proofs (structure that will become clearer when one learns about ideals and/or divisor theory)

Answer (score 0):

Below are a handful of proofs. One should suffice depending on what you already know.

If $\ \color{#0a0}{(a,b)=1}\,$ then $\smash[t]{\ a,b\mid c\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}a\mid \color{#0a0}b\,(c/b)\,\overset{\color{#c00}{\rm(E)}}\Rightarrow\, a\mid c/b\,\overset{\times\ b}\Rightarrow\,ab\mid c\ }$ by $\,\color{#c00}{\rm(E)} =$ [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242).

**Alternatively**, we can use the [GCD Distributive Law $\color{#c0f}{\rm(DL)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/113045/242), or Bezout's Identity for the gcd

$\qquad a,b\mid c\,\Rightarrow\, ab\mid ac,bc\,\Rightarrow\, ab\mid \ (ac,\ \ bc)\ \, \overset{\color{#c0f}{\rm(DL)}} =\ \color{#0a0}{(a,\,b)}c = c\ \ $ by $ \ \ \color{#0a0}{(a,\ b)=1}$

$\qquad a,b\mid c\,\Rightarrow\, ab\mid ac,bc\,\Rightarrow\, ab\mid jac+kbc=\color{#0a0}{(ja\!+\!kb)}c = c\ $ by $\ \color{#0a0}{ja\!+\!kb=1}\ $ by Bezout

**Or** it is an straightforward consequence of the *Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic*, i.e. the *existence* and *uniqueness* of prime factorizations.

**Or**, use the $ $ [gcd * lcm Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3149/242) $\ \gcd(a,b)\,{\rm lcm}(a,b) = ab,\,$ so $\,{\rm lcm}(a,b) = ab\ $ if $\,\gcd(a,b)=1.$