# Distributive law of greatest common divisors.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have seen someone use a distributive law of gcds but I was wondering if anybody could prove that as I am having a little trouble going about this.

Comment: Could you please clarify precisely what law your refer to, and where you are having trouble. The distributive law $\ a\gcd(b,c) = \gcd(ab,ac)\ $ has been discussed here many times in the past, e.g. I gave [four proofs here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/785544/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the "distributive law of greatest common divisors", I assume you mean something like proving that $\gcd(na,nb) = n \cdot \gcd(a,b)$ where $n$, $a$ and $b$ are all natural numbers. If so, this is asked & there are $4$ answers to this at the MSE page [elementary number theory - GCD Proof with Multiplication: gcd(ax,bx) = x$\cdot$gcd(a,b)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112788/gcd-proof-with-multiplication-gcdax-bx-x-cdotgcda-b). A comment says it's the same as [How to prove that $z\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(za,zb)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202397/how-to-prove-that-z-gcda-b-gcdza-zb), and I wouldn't be surprised if there are several other places where this has already been dealt with in MSE.

If you mean something else, please clarify what you are looking for. Thanks.