# $c(kp) = kc(p)$ where $c$ is the content of a polynomial, $p$ a polynomial in $R[x]$ and $k \in R-\{0\}$ (without assuming Gauss' Lemma)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

I have been trying to prove (without assuming Gauss' Lemma) that for $R$ a UFD and
$p(x) \in R[x]$ then for $k \in R- \{0\}$ we have $c(kp) = kc(p)$.

My approach is as follows:
$$
k\cdot c(p) \cdot p''(x) = kp(x) = c(kp)\cdot p'(x) \qquad c(p') = c(p'') = 1
$$
Since $k$ divides the coefficients of $kp(x)$, it divides $c(kp)$ thus $c(kp) = kq$ for some $q \in R$. So canceling $k$'s in the above equation gives
$$
c(p)\cdot p''(x) =p(x) =  q \cdot p'(x)
$$
At this point I'm a bit stuck. I feel as though this little lemma should be a lot simpler than I'm making it. Any advice on how to move forward would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the $\gcd$ law: $\gcd(ma,mb) = m(a,b)$:
Let
\begin{align*}
p'(x) &= a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + x_nx^n \\
p''(x) &= b_0 + b_1x + \cdots + b_nx^n
\end{align*}
(note that they must have the same degree). We have
\begin{align*}
c(qp') &= \gcd(qa_0, qa_1,\dots, qa_n) = q\gcd(a_0,\dots, a_n) = q \\
c\Big(c(p)p''\Big) &= \gcd(c(p)b_0,\dots, c(p)b_n) = c(p)\gcd(b_0,\dots, b_n) = c(p)
\end{align*}
Thus $c(p) = q$ giving us our result.

EDIT: (For completeness, for a proof that $\gcd(ma,mb) = m\gcd(a,b)$ in a UFD see Bill Dubuque's argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112788/gcd-proof-with-multiplication-gcdax-bx-x-cdotgcda-b) )