# How to prove that $z\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(za,zb)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

> I need to prove that $z\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(za,zb)$.

I tried a lot, for example, looking at set of common divisors of the two sides, but I can't conclude anything from that. Can you please give me some advice how I can handle this problem? And $a,b,z \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Try proving that each side of the equation divides the other.

Comment: Ah, and since divisibility is anti-symmetric, we can then conclude that they are equal :)? Thanks!

Comment: While looking at the sets of divisors might give you some intuition, your next reflex would be to *use the definition of gcd*. This is generally the case for mathematics exercises.

Comment: @rschwieb: ... except for those where it isn't, for example exercises that are constructed to train familiarity with a derived property of the concept instead of its definition.

Comment: @HenningMakholm (This is probably all just a misunderstanding. "I should have said "this is generally good practice when doing math exercises", instead of what I said.) Maybe you have an example? I'm not sure how you can divorce a question from the meaning of the terms used in it.

Comment: @rschwieb: For example if the text defines "determinant" as the unique row-linear function on square matrices such that $\det I=1$ and $\det A=0$ whenever the rows of $A$ are linearly dependent, and later proves that $\det(AB) = (\det A)(\det B)$, and you see an exercise asking you to prove that the determinant of a matrix representing a linear map $V\to V$ does not depend on which basis for $V$ you use, **then** reflexively _using the definition of determinant_ is not the most fruitful angle of attack.

Comment: @HenningMakholm OK, good example! I suppose it's a happy accident that what I intended as common-sense advice could be interpreted so seriously. I hope the general message got across to the OP despite being hit with this tangential observation.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112788

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400681/gcd-ca-cb-gcd-a-bc-if-c-0 and
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659924/how-to-prove-gcddm-dn-d-cdot-gcdm-n

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Below are a few proofs of the gcd distributive law $\rm\:(ax,bx) = (a,b)x\:$  using Bezout's identity,  universal gcd laws, and unique factorization. In each proof the first line serves as a hint.

---

First we show that the gcd distributive law follows immediately from the fact that, by Bezout, the [gcd may be specified by linear equations.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112026/242) Distributivity follows because such linear equations are preserved by scalings. Namely, for naturals $\rm\:a,b,c,x \ne 0$

$\rm\qquad\qquad \phantom{ \iff }\ \ \ \:\! c = (a,b) $

$\rm\qquad\qquad \iff\ \: c\:\ |\ \:a,\:b\ \ \ \  \ \ \&\ \ \ \ c\ =\ na\: +\: kb,\ \  \ $ some $\rm\:n,k\in \mathbb Z$

$\rm\qquad\qquad \iff\  cx\ |\ ax,bx\ \ \ \&\ \ \ cx = nax + kbx,\ \,$ some $\rm\:n,k\in \mathbb Z$

$\rm\qquad\qquad { \iff }\ \   cx = (ax,bx) $

The reader familiar with ideals will note that these equivalences are captured more concisely in the distributive law for ideal multiplication $\rm\:(a,b)(x) = (ax,bx),\:$ when interpreted in a PID or Bezout domain, where the ideal $\rm\:(a,b) = (c)\iff c = gcd(a,b)$

---

Alternatively, more generally, in *any* integral domain $\rm\:D\:$ we may employ the [*universal* definitions of GCD, LCM](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/if-a-m-and-a-1-m-prove-aa-1-m/3149#3149) to generalize the above proof.

**Theorem** $\rm\ \ (a,b)\ =\ (ax,bx)/x\ \ $ if $\rm\ (ax,bx)\ $ exists in $\rm\:D.$

**Proof** $\rm\quad\: c\ |\ a,b \iff cx\ |\ ax,bx \iff cx\ |\ (ax,bx) \iff c\ |\ (ax,bx)/x\ \ \ $ **QED**

Such *universal* definitions often serve to simplify proofs, e.g. see [this proof of the GCD * LCM law.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/upper-and-lower-bounds-of-emptyset/3832#3832)

---

Alternatively, comparing powers of primes in unique  factorizations, it reduces to the following
$$ \min(a+c,\,b+c)\ =\ \min(a,b) + c$$

The proof is *precisely* the same as the prior proof, replacing gcd by min, and divides by $\le$, and

$$\begin{eqnarray} {\rm employing}\quad\ c\le a,b&\iff& c\le \min(a,b)\quad&&\rm[universal\  definition\ of\ \ min]\\
\rm the\ analog\ of\quad\   c\  \, |\, \ a,b&\iff&\rm c\ \ |\ \ gcd(a,b)\quad&&\rm[universal\  definition\ of\ \ gcd] \end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: I didn't expect you to answer a question involving gcds.

Comment: Thanks for this large response :)! This answered my question completely :)!

Comment: Actually, if there were a gcd tag, you would be the top user, but you wouldn't care about that distinction.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the first proof because of the following. Can someone please explain to help me understand? $gcd(a,b)$ is the smallest positive $(na+kb)$ for all n, k. So,

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the first proof because of the following. Can someone please explain to help me understand? $gcd(a,b)$ is the smallest positive $(na+kb)$ for all integers $n, k$. So,$gcd(x*a,x*b)$ is smallest positive of $(nax+kbx)$ for all $n, k$. The first proof above simply stated that $cx=nax+kbx$, and thus $cx=x*gcd(a,b)$. How can you be sure that it's the same n and k?

Comment: @leontp587 We are instead using the *equational* characterization of the gcd given in the 2nd equation (common divisor equation & linear dependence relation = Bezout identity). [See here for more on that.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1073618/242). The equivalence follows by multiplying/dividing by $x\neq 0$ in this characterization. This preserves the form of both linear equations.

Answer (score 0):

Write $a=da'$, $b=db'$ with $\gcd(a',b')=1$. Then $za=(zd)a'$, $zb=(zd)b'$ with $\gcd(a',b')=1$. This means that $zd=\gcd(za,zb)$.

I'm using here the following characterization of $\gcd(a,b)$:

> $d=\gcd(a,b)$ iff $a=da'$, $b=db'$ with $\gcd(a',b')=1$.

Here's a proof.

If $d=\gcd(a,b)$ then $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$ and you can write $a=da'$, $b=db'$. If $d'=\gcd(a',b')$, then $dd'$ is also a common divisor of $a$ and $b$. Since $d$ is the greatest common divisor, we have $d=dd'$, which implies $d'=1$.

Conversely, if $a=da'$, $b=db'$ with $\gcd(a',b')=1$ then $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$. Moreover, every *prime* common divisor of $a$ and $b$ must divide $d$ and so every common divisor of $a$ and $b$ divides $d$, which implies $d=\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: Without the precise details of the argument supporting "This means", I cannot exclude the proof from possibly being circular. What proof do you have in mind?

Comment: @BillDubuque, I've added the details.

Comment: Thanks. One step still is not clear. In the lemma's proof, for direction $(\Leftarrow)$, precisely which argument do you intend in order to lift from from every *prime* common divisor to every common divisor. Perhaps induction: cancel $p\,$ then induct on $|c|\,$?