# Prove that if d is a common divisor of a and b, then $d=\gcd(a,b)$ if and only if $\gcd(a/d,b/d)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> Prove that if $d$ is a common divisor of two integers $a$ and $b$, then $d=\gcd(a,b)$ if and only if $\gcd(a/d,b/d)=1$.

So far I used what was given so I have $a=dk$, $b=ld$ and $\gcd(a,b)=d$ can be written as a linear combination of $ax+by=d$ but I am unsure how to use the information.

Where do I go from here? Can someone show me how to solve this using Bezout's Identity if possible?

Comment: Hint: Divide the linear combination you got by $d$.

Comment: so if I do that I have a/d=k and b/d=l 
should I write the gcd(a/d,b/d)=1 as a linear combination of a/d(u)+b/d(v)=1 and substitute those values?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202397

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ By the $ $  [GCD Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242), $ $ and $\ d\mid a,b\iff d\mid (a,b)\ \,$ [[gcd Universal Property]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3356212/242)

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
d\,\left(\dfrac{a}d,\dfrac{b}d\right) &\!\!=& (a,b)\\[.4em]
\Rightarrow\ \left(\dfrac{a}d,\dfrac{b}d\right) &\!\!=& (a,b)\,/\,d\\[.4em]  \!{\rm Thus}\ \ \ 1 = \left(\dfrac{a}d,\dfrac{b}d\right) &\!\!\iff\!& (a,b)\!=\!d\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 0):

Comment: Dividing by d will give the equality $1$, but there is much more to be said. Yes, by definition the smallest positive integer that can be expressed by a linear combination is $1$ which would imply that $1$ is the gcd,but a better way I think is to proceed by contradiction.

So, you have: $\frac{a}{d}+\frac{b}{d}=1$, where $d=\gcd(a,b)$.

Suppose $\gcd(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})$=e. We will show that $e=1$.

Here: $e|\frac{a}{d},e|\frac{b}{d}\Rightarrow \frac{a}{d}=ex, \frac{b}{d}=ey$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$

Thus: $a=dex,b=dey \Rightarrow$ $de$ is a common divisor of $a,b$, but $de>d$ which is a contradiction by assumption of $d=\gcd(a,b)$. Hence, $e=1$.

Comment: can this be solved using a direct proof?