# $ac\equiv bc \pmod{\!m}\!\!\iff\!\! a\equiv b \pmod{\!\!\frac{m}{(c,m)}}$ [Euclid's Lemma, congruence form]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I came across this theorem:

For all integers `a,b,c` and `m>0`, if `d = GCD(c,m)` then `a*c ≡ b*c (mod m)` **iff** `a ≡ b (mod m/d)`.

The `=>`proof states this:

```
a*c ≡ b*c (mod m) => m|(a-b)*c 
                  => m/d | (a-b)*c/d
                  => m/d | (a-b)
                  => a ≡ b (mod m/d)
```

I don't understand how to go from step 2 to step 3. The proof states that this is possible because `m/d` and `c/d` are coprime. To me this means `GCD(m/d, c/d) = 1` but how does this cancel out the whole term?

Comment: That step uses Euclid's Lemma: $\ M\mid C A\,\Rightarrow\ M\mid A\ $ if $\,M\,$ is *coprime* to $\,C.\ $ In your case we have $\, M = m/d,\ \ C = c/d,\ \ A = a\!-\!b.\ \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\frac{m}{d} | (a-b)\frac{c}{d}$ and $GCD(\frac{m}{d}, \frac{c}{d}) = 1$, then $\frac{m}{d}$ must divide $a-b$, because $\frac{m}{d}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$ have no primes in common.

If you still don't have it clear, express $\frac{m}{d}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$ as a product of primes, and see that they can't have primes in common in their factorization, and therefore $\frac{m}{d}$ must divide $a-b$.

Comment: I understand this but I dont understand how you can just remove the whole term. This is saying that `7|14` = `7|(14*2)` since 7 and 2 are coprimes. How can you remove a factor of 2 and still call them equal?

Comment: Nevermind I understand what it says. Its not calling them equal, its implying that that is true! Brain fart :$!

Answer (score 1):

It is special case $\, x = a\!-\!b\,$ below $\, $ [[general Euclid's Lemma]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20112/242)

**Theorem** $\, \ m\mid cx \iff\, \dfrac{m}{(m,c)}\ {\Large \mid}\ x.\ \ \,$  **Proof**  $\,\ $ Let $\ d = (m,c).\ $  Then

we deduce $\, \ m\mid cx \overset{{\rm cancel}\ d\!\!}\iff\ \color{#c00}{\dfrac{m}d}\ {\Large \mid}\ \color{#c00}{\dfrac{c}d}\:x\!\!\overset{\rm(EL)\!}\iff\! \dfrac{m}d\ {\Large \mid}\ x\,\ $ by [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242) (EL),

because: $\,\ (m,c) = d\ \Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{\left(\dfrac{m}d,\,\dfrac{c}d\right)} = (m,c)/d = 1\ $ [via GCD Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696544/prove-that-if-d-is-a-common-divisor-of-a-and-b-then-d-gcda-b-if-and-only-i).

---

**Or** $\,\ m\mid cx\iff m\mid mx,cx\!\!\overset{\rm\color{#0a0}{U}\!}\iff m\mid (mx,cx)\overset{\rm\color{#90f}{D}}=(m,c)x\iff m/(m,c)\mid x$

where we employed  $\,\rm\color{#0a0}{U} =\,$ [gcd Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198801/242) and $\,\rm\color{#90f}{D} = \,$[gcd Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242)