# Proof that $ \frac{a}{e} \equiv \frac{b}{e} \mod \frac{n}{\gcd(n,e)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $a \equiv b \mod n$, then for all positives integers $e$ that divide both $a$ and $b$:
$$ \frac{a}{e} \equiv \frac{b}{e} \mod \frac{n}{\gcd(n,e)}$$

## my try

we know that $$ a\equiv b \mod n\Leftrightarrow ad \equiv bd \mod nd $$
let $$ d:= \frac{1}{\gcd(n,e)} $$
then we have
$$ \frac{a}{\gcd(n,e)} \equiv \frac{b}{\gcd(n,e)} \mod \frac{n}{\gcd(n,e)}$$
but also we know that
$$ \frac{\gcd(n,e)}{e} \equiv \frac{\gcd(n,e)}{e} \mod \frac{n}{\gcd(n,e)}$$
so
$$ \frac{a}{\gcd(n,e)} \cdot \frac{\gcd(n,e)}{e} \equiv \frac{b}{\gcd(n,e)} \cdot  \frac{\gcd(n,e)}{e} \mod \frac{n}{\gcd(n,e)}$$
and we have thesis:
$$ \frac{a}{e} \equiv \frac{b}{e} \mod \frac{n}{\gcd(n,e)}$$
but probably it is wrong because I didn't use all assumptions... can somebody give me hint, how can I solve that and tell me where I failed?

Comment: Generally it is not valid to scale congruences by fractions, so you need to say more to be rigorous.

Answer (score 1):

$n,e\mid a\!-\!b \iff {\rm lcm}(n,e)\mid a\!-\!b \iff \dfrac{ne}{(n,e)}\,{\LARGE \mid }\,a\!-\!b \iff  \dfrac{n}{(n,e)}\,{\LARGE \mid}\, \dfrac{a\!-\!b}e $

---

Alternatively: $\,\ n\ {\LARGE \mid }\ e\ \dfrac{a\!-\!b}e \iff \dfrac{n}{(n,e)}\ {\LARGE \mid }\  \dfrac{a\!-\!b}e\ \,$ via [general Euclid's Lemma.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/742649/242)

Comment: We use $\ (x,y) := \gcd(x,y),\, $ which is standard notation in number theory.