# $\ ac≡bc\pmod{\! m}\!\iff\! a≡b\pmod {\!m/d},\ d = \gcd(c,m)\ $ [Congruence Cancellation & Division Rule]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How would you show that if $ac≡bc$ $\mod m$ and $\gcd(c,m)=d$, then  $a≡b$ $\mod \frac{m}{d}$?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have marked this under proof writing. So I will attempt a model proof.

So $ac \equiv bc \pmod{m}$, which means that $m \mid ac-bc$, and hence $m \mid c(a-b)$. Hence, $c(a-b)=km$ for some integer $k$. Now, Given that $\gcd(c,m) =d $, it follows that $c=xd$ and $m=yd$ for some *co-prime* integers $x$ and $y$. Hence,
$$
c(a-b) = km \implies xd(a-b) = kyd \implies x(a-b) = ky
$$
Note that $x \mid ky$ from the above, and recall that $x$ is co-prime to $y$. We claim that $x$ divides $k$. (Thanks to @curioushuman for asking for the details).

Indeed, since $x$ divides $ky$, suppose that $xz = ky$ for some integer $z$. By Bezout's theorem, as $x$ is coprime to $y$ there exist $a,b$ integers such that $ax+by=1$. Multiply by $k$ to get $akx+bky=k$, then note that $ky=xz$, so $akx+bzx = k$, the same as $(ak+bz)x = k$. Thus, $x$ divides $k$ since $ak+bz$ is an integer.

Thus, $\frac{k}{x}$ is an integer. Now, $$
(a-b) = \frac{k}{x}y
$$
and hence $a-b$ is a multiple of $y$. Hence $a \equiv b \pmod{y}$. But $y = \frac{m}{d}$, hence $a \equiv b \pmod{\dfrac{m}{d}}$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me!! How can you say that $x$ and $y$ are co-prime?

Comment: Suppose $x$ and $y$ are not co-prime. Then let $x = gw$ and $y=gz$, where $g \neq 1$. Then note that $c=xd=gwd$,and $m = yd = gzd$. Note that $gd$ divides both $x$ and $y$ and is greater than $d$ because $g>1$. This contradicts the fact that $d$ is the gcd of $m$ and $c$. Hence $x$ and $y$ are co-prime.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how it's true: "*Note that gd divides both $x$ and $y$*", and I ended up thinking that you meant not "$x$ and $y$", but "$c$ and $m$", then the proof on "*why $x$ and $y$ are co-prime*" makes sense. Thank you, btw!

Comment: And I do not understand, why "*because $x$ is co-prime to $y$, it follows that $x|k$*"? How can one prove it?

Comment: @curioushuman Give me a few minutes, I'll read through my own answer and your comment and provide an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @curioushuman Suppose that $x$ is co-prime to $y$ and $x$ divides $ky$ for some integer $k$. Since $x$ divides $ky$, suppose that $xz = ky$ for some integer $z$. By Bezout's theorem, as $x$ is coprime to $y$ there exist $a,b$ integers such that $ax+by=1$. Multiply by $k$ to get $akx+bky=k$, then note that $ky=xz$, so $akx+bzx = k$, the same as $(ak+bz)x = k$. Thus, $x$ divides $k$ since $ak+bz$ is an integer. Let me edit that into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming integers for all variables, and $c' = c/d$, $m' = m/d$ :

$$\begin{align}
ac \equiv bc \pmod m &\iff \exists k ~~ ac - bc = km  \\
%
                     &\iff \exists k ~~ ac'd - bc'd \equiv km \\
%
                     &\iff \exists k ~~ a - b \equiv (k/c')(m/d)
\end{align}$$

So we have to establish that $k / c'$ is an integer.  From $\gcd(c, m) = d$ we can infer $\gcd(c', m') = 1$, so

$$ac - bc = km$$
  $$ac'd - bc'd \equiv k(m'd)$$
  $$c'(a - b) = km'$$

So $c'$ divides $k$, so $k/c'$ is an integer.

$$\exists j ~ a - b = j(m/d)$$
$$a \equiv b \pmod {m/d}$$

Answer (score 2):

By definition $\ ac\equiv bc\pmod{\! m}\!\iff\! m\mid \color{#0a0}c\:\!(\overbrace{a\!-\!b}^{\textstyle \color{#0a0}n})\!\iff m/(m,c)\mid a\!-\!b,\,$ by

**Theorem** $ $ [(general Euclid's Lemma)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20112/242) $\ \ \ m\mid \color{#0a0}{cn}\iff m/(m,c)\mid n \ \  $

**Remark** $ $ As is explained carefully [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242), in **fraction** language this can be written as

$$ ac\equiv bc\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!m}\iff a\equiv \dfrac{bc}c\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!m}\equiv\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\underbrace{\dfrac{bc/\color{#c00}d}{c/\color{#c00}d}\equiv b\!\!\!\pmod{\!m/\color{#c00}d}}_{\textstyle {\rm cancel}\ \color{#c00}d\!=\!(c,m)\,\ \color{#c00}{\rm everywhere}}\qquad\qquad$$

The common divisor $\,\color{#c00}d = (c,m)\,$ must be cancelled $\:\!\rm\color{#c00}{everywhere}\:\!$ (top, bottom **and modulus**), leaving the new denominator $\,c/d\,$  *coprime* to the new modulus $\,m/d,\,$ so invertible, so cancellable. Generally, the modular fraction $\,e/c\bmod m\,$ exists $\!\iff (c,m)\mid e,\,$  true here by: $\,d\!=\!(c,m)\mid c\mid bc.\,$ However, when $d>1$ the modular fraction is *multi-valued* $\!\bmod m,\,$ but single-valued $\!\bmod m/d,\,$ see the prior linked post for details.

Comment: Did you mean $ ac\equiv bc\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!m}\iff a\equiv \dfrac{bc}c\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!m}\color{green}\iff\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\underbrace{\dfrac{bc/\color{#c00}d}{c/\color{#c00}d}\equiv b\!\!\!\pmod{\!m/\color{#c00}d}}_{\textstyle {\rm cancel}\ \color{#c00}d\!=\!(c,m)\,\ \color{#c00}{\rm everywhere}}\qquad$ or not?

Comment: @J.W.T  No, I mean what I wrote. Follow the link to see what it means.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, in two steps: $ $ first cancel $\,d = (c,m)\,$ $\rm\color{#c00}{everywhere}$ to reduce to [the case of](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/696611/242) $\rm\color{#0a0}{coprime}$ $\,\bar c,\bar m = c/d, m/d,\,$ then cancel $\,\bar c\,$ by scaling by $\,\bar c^{-1}$ ([exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242) $\!\bmod \bar m$ by $\,\bar c\,$ $\rm\color{#0a0}{coprime}$ to $\,\bar m)$

$\qquad\quad\ \ \begin{align}  
ac &\equiv bc\!\!\pmod{m}\\[.2em]
\smash[t]{\overset{\bf\color{#0af}{L1}\!}\iff}\ \ \ a\bar c&\equiv b\bar c\!\!\!\pmod{\bar m}\ \ \ {\rm via\ cancel\ } d = (c,m)\ \,\&\,\ \rm {\bf\color{#0af}{L1}}\ below\\[.2em]
\iff\ \ \ \ a &\equiv b\pmod{\bar m}\  {\rm\ \ by\ scaling\ by\ }\, \bar c^{-1}
\end{align}$

---

$\bf\color{#0af}{L1}$ $ $ If $\, d\mid c,m\!:\ ac\equiv bc\pmod{\!m}\!\!\iff\! {ac/\color{#c00}d \equiv bc/\color{#c00}d\pmod{\!m/\color{#c00}d}}\ $ [cancel $\,d\ \rm\color{#c00}{everywhere}$]

$\!\begin{align}{\bf Proof}\quad \exists\:\! k\!:\quad\  ac &= bc + km\\[.2em]
\iff\  \exists\:\! k\!:\  ac/d &= bc/d \,+\, k\:m/d,\ \ \text{via cancel $\,d$}\\[.2em] 
\iff\ \qquad ac/d &\equiv bc/d\!\!\!\pmod{\!m/d} \\[.2em]
{\rm i.e.} \ \ \ \ \ a\bar c\, &\equiv\, b\bar c\,\pmod{\!\bar m}\end{align}$

**Remark** $\ $ The (two-step) cancellation has a natural view as modular fraction reduction as explained in the remark in my other answer here. The first step reducing to coprime $\bar c,\bar m\,$ is a special case of *homogeneous reduction* as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20112/242).

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $ac\equiv bc \pmod{m}$ means that there exists a $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $ac=bc+km$. If $d=\gcd(c,m)$, let $c=sd$ and $m=td$ (note now that $\gcd(s,t)=1$). This means that
$$
\begin{aligned}
ac &\equiv bc \pmod{m} \Longleftrightarrow \\
ac &= bc+km \Longleftrightarrow \\
asd &= bsd+ktd \Longleftrightarrow \\
as &= bs+kt,
\end{aligned}
$$
so $as\equiv bs \pmod{t}$, or in other words $as\equiv bs \pmod{m/d}$. But since $\gcd(s,t)=1$ we can conclude that $a\equiv b \pmod{m/d}$, and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem.**

$$\forall a, b, c \in \mathbf{Z}, n \in \mathbf{Z}^*, \quad ac \equiv bc \pmod n \iff a \equiv b \pmod{\tfrac{n}{\gcd(c, n)}}.$$

**Proof.** Let $a, b, c \in \mathbf{Z}, n \in \mathbf{Z}^*$.

$$
\begin{align}
  ac \equiv bc \pmod n & \iff \exists k \in \mathbf{Z}, ac - bc = kn \\
                       & \iff \exists k \in \mathbf{Z}, (a - b)c = kn \\
                       & \iff \exists k \in \mathbf{Z}, (a - b) \frac{c}{\gcd(c, n)} = k\frac{n}{\gcd(c, n)}.
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, $\frac{c}{\gcd(c, n)}$ divides $k\frac{n}{\gcd(c, n)}$, and since $\frac{c}{\gcd(c, n)}$ is [coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) to $\frac{n}{\gcd(c, n)}$, it follows from [Euclid’s lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) that $\frac{c}{\gcd(c, n)}$ divides $k$, hence

$$
\begin{align}
  ac \equiv bc \pmod n & \iff \exists k \in \mathbf{Z}, a - b = \frac{k}{\frac{c}{\gcd(c, n)}} \frac{n}{\gcd(c, n)} \\
                       & \iff \exists l \in \mathbf{Z}, a - b = l \frac{n}{\gcd(c, n)} \\
                       & \iff a \equiv b \pmod{\tfrac{n}{\gcd(c, n)}}. & \blacksquare
\end{align}
$$