# Vinogradov's proof that $U_{p^{\alpha}}$ is cyclic. How to prove $p^{r-1} (p-1) \mid \delta$ for $1 \leq r \leq \alpha$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, cyclic-groups, primitive-roots

The proof of Vinogradov that $U_{p^{\alpha}}$ ($\alpha \geq 1$) is cyclic for an odd prime $p$, has a part that I don't understand.

We take $g$ a primitive root of $U_p$.

And, at a certain point of the proof, Vinogradov says:
[image]

[image]

I don't understand how he gets that $\delta = p^{r-1} (p-1)$.

I understand that $\delta \mid p^{r-1} (p-1)$ for any $1\leq r\leq \alpha$.

But my problem is to prove the other divisibility, namely: $$p^{r-1} (p-1) \mid \delta  \tag{1}$$.

My guess on this is that there are two possible ways of proving $(1)$.

First way would be to prove that $p^{r-1} \mid \delta$ for every $1\leq r\leq \alpha$. Then, as $p^{r-1}$ is prime with $(p-1)$ (and as $p-1 \mid \delta$) we could arrive to the desired result $(1)$.

Second way would be to use an order argument i.e. to prove that $p^{r-1} (p-1)$ is the order of some element and that this same element raised to the power $\delta$ is congruent to $1$. I still haven't figured out if this second way would take place modulo $p$ or modulo $p^{\alpha}$. Nonetheless, I doubt this could happen modulo $p$ because in $U_p$, $p-1$ is already the maximal order that we can have, so how could $p^{r-1} (p-1)$ be a valid order ?

PS: Here is the beginning of the proof:[image]

In this beginning of the proof, the equalities in the left bracket might help to use an "order argument" (the second way) but I don't really know how.

Thanks

Comment: $p\!-\!1\mid \delta \,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{\delta = n(p\!-\!1)},\,$ so $\ \color{#c00}\delta\mid p^{\alpha-1}(p\!-\!1)$ $\iff \color{#c00}{n(p\!-\!1)}\mid p^{\alpha-1}(p\!-\!1)$ $\color{#0a0}\iff n\mid p^{\alpha-1}$ $\iff n = 1,p,p^2,\ldots,p^{\alpha-1},\,$ where we used $\,nb\mid ab\color{#0a0}\iff n\mid a\,$ (by [cancelling](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3590567/242) $\,b\neq 0)\ \ $

Comment: It seems that you may have confused quantifiers. The argument shows that $\,\delta = n(p-1) = p^{r-1}(p-1)\,$ for *some* positive  $\,r\le \alpha,\,$ i.e. where $\,n\,$ is *some* divisor of $\,p^{\alpha-1}\ \ $