# What should I type in Archive.org search bar to find books covering proof of $U_{p^α}$ is cyclic (where $p$ is an odd prime)?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, cyclic-groups

> Let $p$ be an odd prime number. The multiplicative group modulo $p^α$, $U_{p^α}$, is cyclic for all $α\geq 1$.

I have read proofs of this result in Vinogradov "Elements of number theory" (published in 1954) and in Ireland "A classical introduction to modern number theory" (1982) but could not fully understand them (see my post: [Vinogradov's proof that $U_{p^{\alpha}}$ is cyclic. How to prove $p^{r-1} (p-1) \mid \delta$ for $1 \leq r \leq \alpha$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4831525/vinogradovs-proof-that-u-p-alpha-is-cyclic-how-to-prove-pr-1-p-1)).

I am really willing to understand this result, by reading other proofs of this result (be it a similar proof, written by another author, or be it another proof, i.e. another valid way of proving it).

The result seems to be a pretty classical one. However I do not know which keywords to type in the [archive](https://archive.org/) search bar (Archive is an online librairy) to find books covering the subject.

I've been thinking about "introduction in number theory" or "elementary group theory" but is seems to be too wide a scope.

Thank you.

Comment: A good topic is "primitive roots" which should discuss the theorem saying $n$ has a primitive root iff $n=2,4,p^k,2p^k$ which shows what you want. Note a primitive root is a residue mod n whose powers contain all residues coprime to n.

Comment: Well funnily enough, I typed "primitive root" in Archive search bar, and it retrieved religious books (because of the "other" meaning of *root* I think)

Comment: try "primitive root theorem" or "number theory primitive root". [I had no idea what an assortment of topics on archive...]

Comment: archive.org is certainly not the best source for modern math text books.