# Modular Arithmetic: Proofs

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

My teacher asked me the following question:

If $a \equiv 8 \mod{16}$   then $2a \equiv 16 \mod{32}$.

I solved this problem by plugging in a bunch of numbers but I wonder if I can prove it in a more abstract way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That' s obvious  from the formula of the Euclidean division. Furthermore, you also have $2a\equiv 0\mod 16$.

Comment: Use the definition. What does it mean that $a\equiv8\bmod16$? Then, what can you say about $2a$?

Comment: Maybe try the definition of modular congruence, i mean, try to prove that, if $16\vert (a-8)$ then $32\vert(2a - 16)$

Comment: $a\equiv8\pmod{16}$ **means that** $(a-8)/16$ is an integer. $2a\equiv16\pmod{32}$ **means that** $(2a-16)/32$ is an integer.

Comment: For the reverse inference - cancelling or division - see [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1883921/242)