# Problem in a GCD proof

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

[image: from David burton][image: page 2]

On the second page, $c$ is considered an arbitrary positive constant, also $c$ divides $ax+by$ - which means $ax+by=kc$.

If by chance $x/k$ and $y/k$ belong to integers, $c$ will belong to set $S$ and $c$ will be smaller than the least element $d$. 
Isn't that a contradiction? 
Where am i wrong?

Comment: $c$ isn't an arbitrary positive constant, it is an arbitrary positive common divisor of $a,b$. Also, if $a/k$ and $b/k$ are integers, then you can solve $\frac{a}{k}x+\frac{b}{k}y=c$, but that doesn't mean $c\in S$, because $c$ needs to be writen as $aX+bY=c$. You can't convert the first to the second.

Comment: @user282856 Do you mean $x/k$ and $y/k$ belong to integers?

Comment: @ntntnt yes, thanks.

Comment: Btw, Which book is this? Burton?

Comment: @Vidyanshu Mishra Yes, this is D.M. Burton's "Elementary Number Theory."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $c$ is an arbitrary positive common divisor of the non-zero integers $a$ and $b$ (trivial if either integer equals $0$) and $\gcd(a,b) = d$. Then $\exists$ $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$a = pc \qquad b = qc$$

Consequently, we can substitute into $ax+by$ to get

$$(pc)x+(qc)y = d \implies c(px + qy) = d$$

So $px + qy$ is what $k$ is explicitly equal to. Now, if we attempt to do what you propose, we find that

$$a \Big(\frac{x}{px+qy} \Big) + b \Big(\frac{y}{px+qy} \Big) = c$$

If $px + qy = 1$, then there is no issue as it is clear that, in fact, $c = d$ and we do not contradict the minimality of $d$. If, on the other hand, we suppose that $px + qy > 1$ (which would make $c < d$), then the expressions

$$\frac{x}{px+qy} \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{y}{px+qy}$$

are not in the form $X$, $Y$ as mentioned in the comments. In fact,

**Question: Is either expression an integer?**

To investigate this, let us first note that at least one of $x$ or $y$ must be non-zero, or else $d = 0$. Without loss of generality, let $x \neq 0$ and $x/(px+qy) \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $\exists \ m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$x = m(px+qy) \implies x(1-mp) = mqy$$

Rewriting the second expression in the following manner:

$$\frac{y}{px+qy} = \Big(\frac{mq}{mq} \Big) \frac{y}{px+qy}$$

(This is legal since $b \neq 0 \implies q \neq 0$ and $x \neq 0 \implies m \neq 0$). Substituting for $mqy$ gives us

$$\frac{x(1-mp)}{mq(px+qy)} = \frac{x(1-mp)}{xq} = \frac{1-mp}{q} \quad \Big( = \frac{y}{px+qy} \Big)$$

if $y = 0$, then we force $mp = 1 \implies m = p = \pm 1$. Then $a = \pm c \implies b = \pm qa$, contradicting the generality of our choice of the integers $a, b$. Otherwise, if $y \neq 0$ and $y/(px+qy) \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$1 - mp = kq \implies 1 = p\cdot(m) + q\cdot(k)$$

The equality implies that $p, q$ are relatively prime, for $\gcd(p,q) = 1 \iff$ we can write a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of $p,q$ equal to 1. But then this implies that $c = d$, contradicting both the hypotheses that $c < d$ and $px + qy > 1$. Note that this is true by referring to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696544/prove-that-if-d-is-a-common-divisor-of-a-and-b-then-d-gcda-b-if-and-only-i) and observing that $a/c = p, b/c = q,$ and

\begin{align}\frac{a}{c} (m) + \frac{b}{c} (k) = 1 &\iff \gcd \Big(\frac{a}{c},\frac{b}{c} \Big) = 1 \\
& \iff c = \gcd(a,b) = d
\end{align}

Thus it follows that $c \notin S$.