# Prove $\gcd(ka,kb) = k*\gcd(a,b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, divisibility

For all $k > 0,\ k\in \Bbb Z$ . Prove 
$$\gcd(k*a,\ k*b) = k *\gcd(a,\ b)$$

I think I understand  what this wants but I can't figure out how to set up a formal proof. These are the guidelines we have to follow

[image]

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked quite a few questions recently. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Comment: ok thank you for warning me :) I wasn't aware of the limit

Comment: This questions was shown (as the top one) among related questions on the right: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202397/how-to-prove-that-z-cdot-textgcda-b-textgcdza-zb

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Start with the fact that $\gcd(k a, k b)$ is the minimal positive value of $s k a + t k b$, and factor out $k$.