# Prove GCD of polynomials is same when coefficients are in a different field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

Prove that the greatest common divisor of two polynomials $f, g$ in $\Bbb Q[X]$ is equal to their
greatest common divisor in $\Bbb C[X]$.

I am having trouble writing this proof. I tried setting it up like:

$f(x) = p(x)f'(x)$

$g(x) = p(x)g'(x)$

where $p(x)$ is the gcd. Suppose that the gcd in $\Bbb C[X]$ is $q(x)$, $p(x) \not = q(x)$.

$f(x) = q(x)f''(x)$

$g(x) = q(x)g''(x)$

...but I am getting no where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ gcds in a PID $\rm D$ such as $\,\Bbb Q[x]\,$ persist in extension rings because the gcd may be specified by the solvability of (linear) equations over $\rm D$  and such solutions always persist in extension rings, i.e. roots in $\rm D$ remain roots in rings $\rm\,R \supset D.\:$ More precisely, the [Bezout identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) for the gcd yields the following ring-theoretic equational specification for the gcd

$$\begin{eqnarray} \rm\gcd(a,b) = c &\iff&\rm (a,b) = (c)\ \ \ {\rm [equality\ of\  ideals]}\\
&\iff&\rm  a = c\:\!\color{#C00}x,\  b = c\:\!\color{#C00} y,\,\ a\:\!\color{#C00} u + b\:\! \color{#C00}v = c\ \  has\ roots\ \ \color{#C00}{x,y,u,v}\in D\end{eqnarray}$$

**Proof** $\ (\Leftarrow)\:$ In any ring $\rm R,\:$  $\rm\:a= c\:\! x ,\ b = c\:\! y\:$ have roots $\rm\:x,y\in R$ $\iff$ $\rm c\ |\ a,b\:$ in $\rm R.$ Further if $\rm\:c = a\: u + b\: v\:$ has roots $\rm\:u,v\in R\:$ then $\rm\:d\ |\ a,b$ $\:\Rightarrow\:$ $\rm\:d\ |\ a\:u+b\:v = c\:$ in $\rm\: R.\:$ Hence we infer $\rm\:c = gcd(a,b)\:$ in $\rm\: R,\:$ being a common divisor divisible by every common divisor. $\ (\Rightarrow)\ $ If $\rm\:c = gcd(a,b)\:$ in $\rm D$ then the Bezout identity  implies the existence of such roots $\rm\:u,v\in D.\ \small\bf  QED$

Rings with such *linearly* representable gcds are known as *Bezout* rings. As above, gcds in such rings always persist in extension rings. In particular, coprime elements remain coprime in extension rings (with same $1$). This need not be true without such Bezout linear representations of the gcd. For example, $\rm\:\gcd(2,x) = 1\:$ in $\rm\:\mathbb Z[x]\:$ but the gcd is the nonunit  $\:2\:$ in $\rm\:\mathbb Z[x/2]\subset \mathbb Q[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest approach is to study an algorithm for computing the gcd.

Answer (score 1):

First, do not write factors as $f'(x)$ since it looks like the derivative. Second, you are not getting anywhere because your equations do *not* capture the condition that $p(x)$ is the gcd, but only that it is a common factor. You will make no progress unless your conditions truly convey that you are working with a gcd rather than just a common factor of $f$ and $g$. You need to somehow use that the complementary factors are relatively prime. Use Bezout's identity for relatively prime polynomials.