# Infinitude of irreducible polynomials $\pmod 2$

Tags: number-theory

How can I prove that there is an infinite amount of irreducible polynomials $\pmod 2$?

Comment: How do you prove that there is an infinite amount of primes?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222025/there-are-infinitely-many-irreducible-polynomials-in-bbbf-px

Comment: Here, [Number of monic irreducible polynomials of prime degree p over finite fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40811/number-of-monic-irreducible-polynomials-of-prime-degree-p-over-finite-fields), is discussed Gauss's formula for counting the irreducible polynomials of a general degree $n\gt 0$ over a finite field.  So since there are irreducible polynomials of every degree, there are infinitely many of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are  fintely many, multiply them together and add 1. This polynomial is not divisible by any of the finite set. So it should have a new irreducible factor.

In fact there is an irreducible polynomial of any degree $>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ is UFD. Do you know the Euclid’s proof of infinitude of primes?