# Let $F,K$ be two fields $F \subset K$ and suppose $f(x),g(x) \in F[x]$ are relatively prime in $F[x].$ Prove they are relatively prime in $K[x].$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory

> Let $F,K$ be two fields $F \subset K$ and suppose $f(x),g(x) \in F[x]$ are relatively prime in $F[x].$ Prove they are relatively prime in $K[x].$

Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are relatively prime in $F[x].$ Then there exist $\mu(x), \lambda(x) \in F[x]$ such that $\mu(x) f(x) + \lambda(x) g(x) = 1.$ Since $F[x] \subset K[x]$ it follows that $\mu(x), \lambda(x) \in K[x]$ also. Thus  $\mu(x) f(x) + \lambda(x) g(x) = 1$ in $K[x] \Longrightarrow f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are relatively prime in $K[x]. \Box$

Is this the correct reasoning? Am I missing any details?

Comment: Nope, you're good!

Comment: Awesome, thanks :)

Comment: Dupe of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061862/prove-gcd-of-polynomials-is-same-when-coefficients-are-in-a-different-field/1073618#1073618) and others.

Comment: The more interesting aspect is that the converse is true: if $f$ and $g$ in $F[x]$ are relatively prime in $K[x]$, where $F \subset K$, then they are relatively prime in $F[x]$.

Comment: KCd, could you elaborate your comment please ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(x)$ is relatively prime to $g(x)$ in $F[x]$. If $f(x), g(x)$ are not relatively prime in $K[x]$, they must have a common root in some extension $E$ of $K$, so $F\subseteq K\subseteq E$. Therefore, by [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3615140/120815), $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have a common factor of positive degree in $F[x]$; a contradiction.

Conversely, if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have a common factor in $F[x]$,
clearly they have the same common factor in $K[x]$.  This proves the contrapositive.