# Subgroup that generates $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

For reference, the example in question is taken from Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Gallian):

$$\left< 8, 13 \right> = \mathbb{Z}$$

My first question is to confirm that this is saying  that $8a+13b=n$, where $a,b,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and that $n$ can take on any integer, hence $\left<8, 13 \right> = \mathbb{Z}$.

My second question is how can I pick an $n$ value and find out the necessary values for $a$ and $b$. For example, when $n=4, a=2,b=-1$, but what if I wanted to be able to find $a$ and $b$ for any $n$?

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you need to do is find a combination $8a+13b=1$. From this one you can get any other, by multiplying by $n$.

To find the required combination use the extended euclidean algorithm:

$13=8+5$

$8=5+3$

$5=3+2$

$3=2+1$

Now we flip the equalities:

$1=3-2$

$2=5-3$

$3=8-5$

$5=13-8$

Then we use them recursively to get a combination of $8$ and $13$:

$1=3-2=3-(5-3)=2(3)-5=2(8-5)-5=2(8)-3(5)=2(8)-3(13-8)=$

$5(8)-3(13)$

Comment: +1 for the wonderful algorithm for finding $a\ \&\ b$ .!!

Comment: It's worth noting that such an $a$ and $b$ will exist precisely when the two numbers, here $8$ and $15$, are coprime.

Comment: One can also use continued fractions to find $a,b$, See for example, "The Solution of equations in Integers" by A.O.Gelfond, published by P.Noordhopf Ltd, Griningen, 1960.

Answer (score 0):

The solution comes from a *Bézout's relation* between $8$ and $13$, e.g.
$$5\cdot 13-8\cdot 8=1,$$
from which you deduce
$$5n\cdot 13 -8n\cdot 8=n.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**   $\ a\Bbb Z + b \Bbb Z = c\Bbb Z\iff \gcd(a,b) = c\,\ $  since

$ c\Bbb Z \supseteq a\Bbb Z+b\Bbb Z\iff a,b\in c\Bbb Z\iff \color{}{c\mid a,b}$

$c\Bbb Z \subseteq a\Bbb Z+b\Bbb Z\iff c \in a\Bbb Z+b\Bbb Z\iff  c=aj+bk\,$ for some $\,j,k\in\Bbb Z$

Thus $\ a\Bbb Z + b \Bbb Z = c\Bbb Z\iff c\mid a,b\,\ $ and $\,\  c=aj+bk\,$ for some $\,j,k\in\Bbb Z$

But the latter is a [very well-known equational characterization](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1073618/242) of the gcd. Thus your question reduces to standard comptations with the [(extended) Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/616893/242), i.e. use the algorithm to compute the Bezout equation for the gcd, then scale that to obtain reps for all multiples of the gcd.