# Property of GCD in UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a unique factorization domain (UFD). Let $a,b,c\in R$.

Prove that $\text{gcd}(ca,cb)=c \times\text{gcd}(a,b)$.

**Proof:** We know that since R-UFD then R-GCD domain. Suppose that $d=\text{gcd}(a,b)$ then we need to prove that $cd=\text{gcd}(ca,cb)$.

1) It is easy to see that $cd|ca$ and $cd|cb$.

2) We need to show that if $x|ca$ and $x|cb$ then $x|cd$. But unfortunately I am not able prove that.

I guess that here we need to use that $d=\text{gcd}(a,b)$.

Would be very grateful if anyone show to prove that 2) holds.

Comment: See  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400681/gcd-ca-cb-gcd-a-bc-if-c-0), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202397/how-to-prove-that-z-gcda-b-gcdza-zb), and the links, which also works for $R$ not $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thanks for links! I also proved it by considering cases.

Comment: @RFZ: Would you mind posting your proof as an Answer, to remove this question from the unanswered list?