# How to prove $\gcd(dm,dn)=d\cdot\gcd(m,n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I want to prove the following equation :
$$
(dm,dn) = d\cdot(m,n) 
$$
where 
$$
(m,n) = \gcd(m,n) \\
(dm,dn) = \gcd(dm,dn)
$$
I tried this :
$$
(dm,dn) \rightarrow \exists g_1 \in Z : g_1|dm, g_1|dn \rightarrow g_1|(dm\cdot x+dn\cdot y) \rightarrow g_1|d\cdot (mx+ny) \\
\rightarrow g_1=\frac{d\cdot (mx+ny)}{t}
$$
And the same for $ (m,n)$ :
$$
g_2=\frac{mx+ny}{t}
$$
If i insert $g_1$ and $g_2$ i get :
$$
d\cdot\frac{mx+ny}{t}=d\cdot \frac{mx+ny}{t}
$$

Is this right?

Comment: Suggestions: What do your $\rightarrow$'s mean?  How are $x$ and $y$ defined?

Comment: Since the gcd is defined to be non-negative, you have to assume $d\ge 0$ or use $|d|$ on the RHS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also deduce it by [Bézout's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity):

Put $g:=(m,n)$ and $G:=(dm,dn)$. There exist integers $a,b$ such that $$an+bm=g.$$

Therefore $a(dn)+b(dm)=dg$, what implies that $G|dg$.

On the other hand, since $g|m$ and $g|n$ we get $dg|dm$ and $dg|dn$. Hence $dg|G$ and thus $G=dg$.

Answer (score 1):

The $\gcd$ is the product of the prime factors of the two numbers, taken with their minimum multiplicities.

Multiplying both by a third number increases the multiplicities identically, and increases the minimum the same way (by $\min(a+c,b+c)=\min(a,b)+c$).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've shown that the two $t$-s are the same. Try using the formula that $\mbox{lcm}(a,b)\cdot\gcd(a,b)=ab$ to solve for $\gcd(dm,dn)$.