# How to prove $\gcd(a_1,\dots,ka_i,ka_{i+1},\dots,a_n) \mid k\cdot\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_i,a_{i+1},\dots,a_n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

How to prove:
$$\gcd(a_1,\dots,k*a_i,k*a_{i+1},\dots,a_n) \mid k\cdot\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_i,a_{i+1},\dots,a_n)$$

maybe i have to change this question? I'm just reading a contest solution [Codeforces Round #410 (Div. 2) Editorial](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/51652)

In problem C he use that $$\gcd(a_1,\dots,2*a_i,2*a_{i+1},\dots,a_n)\mid2\cdot\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_i,a_{i+1},\dots,a_n)$$

Comment: I just don't know how to prove it with mathematical words.

Comment: What about if k=2?

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: Just two of the $a_j$'s multiplied by $k$? Or all of them?

Comment: @Magdiragdag just two

Comment: This follows from stronger claim that $\gcd(ka_1,\dots,ka_n) = k \gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n)$.
Combined with the fact that $\gcd(a_1,\dots,ka_i,ka_{i+1},\dots,a_n) \mid \gcd(ka_1,\dots,ka_i,ka_{i+1},\dots,ka_n)$ you get the claim you are asking about. Maybe you can start by thinking about two variables rather than $n$, i.e., proof that $\gcd(ka,kb)=k\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: For the case of two variables, you should be able to find several posts on this site. For example this one: [How to prove that $z\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(za,zb)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/202397). And also other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/202397). You might find some other similar posts [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cgcd(ka%2Ckb)%24&p=1).