# GCD of multiple elements in a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, gcd-and-lcm, unique-factorization-domains

> Suppose that the GCD of $a_1,..,a_r$ is a unit. Show that the GCD of $ka_1,..,ka_r$ is $k$, where $k\in R$.

Its seems simple enough but I can't seem to show that any divisor of $ka_1,..,ka_r$ can divide $k$, i.e. i tried to show the (k) was the smallest principal ideal that contains $ka_1,..,ka_r$.

Comment: Can you just show for the case $r = 2$ and then use induction on $r$?

Comment: I'm having trouble with the 2 case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $r=2$ case follows from a theorem dealt with [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202397/how-to-prove-that-z-gcda-b-gcdza-zb); induction (or extending the methodology there) will help with the general case.