# Prove that $\gcd(pf,pg) = p \cdot \gcd(f,g)$ when $p,f,g$ are polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

How does one start proving this theory?

Prove:
$$\gcd(pf,pg) = p \cdot \gcd(f,g)$$
when
$$p,f,g \in \mathbb F[x] \;,\;\text{The max power multiplier of $p$ is 1 (fixed polynomial)}.$$

Comment: How would you work with GCDs to begin with? Write out any characterizations or definitions you know and see where you get with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

What's the GCD$(ak,bk)$, if GCD$(a,b)=1$?

For example: Let $a(x)=x^2+x+2$ and $b(x)=x^2+x+1$. Clearly, GCD$(a(x),b(x))=1$

If you multiply $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ with some polynomial $k(x)$, you will have GCD of new polynomials to be $k(x)$.

Comment: It is $k$ I would take a wild guess?

Comment: Yes. Try out with some small numbers. You will see why.! :)

Comment: So I guess, assume $gcd(f,g) = d(x)$, so, I would take a wild guess and say that $gcd(pf,pg) = p \times d$
I guess my proof should start from that idea, yes? only thing still to prove is that $p \times d$ is really $gcd(pf,pg)$, or $p \times gcd(f,g)$

Comment: Polynomials are function of numbers. GCD$(a,b)=d \implies a=a_1.d$ and $b=b_1.d$. Then $pa$ and $pb$ can be written in terms of $d$ and so on. . .

Answer (score 1):

Inceptio's hint will let you prove that equality whenever your polynomial ring is a UFD. If you assume that $\Bbb F$ is a field, though, it may be easier to recall that $\Bbb F[X]$ is a PID...

Answer (score 0):

Below are three proofs of the **gcd distributive law** $\rm\ (ax,bx) = (a,b)x\ $  using Bezout's identity,  universal gcd laws, and unique factorization.

---

First we show that the gcd distributive law follows immediately from the fact that, by Bezout, the [gcd may be specified by linear equations.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112026/242) Distributivity follows because such linear equations are preserved by scalings. Namely, for  $\rm\:a,b,c,x \ne 0\:$ in a domain $\rm\:D\:$ satisfying Bezout's identity

$\rm\qquad\qquad \phantom{ \iff }\ \ \ \:\! c = (a,b) $

$\rm\qquad\qquad \iff\ \: c\:\ |\ \:a,\:b\ \ \ \  \ \ \&\ \ \ \ c\ =\ ja\: +\: kb,\ \  \ $ some $\rm\:j,k\in D$

$\rm\qquad\qquad \iff\  cx\ |\ ax,bx\ \ \ \&\ \ \ cx = jax + kbx,\ \,$ some $\rm\:j,k\in D$

$\rm\qquad\qquad { \iff }\ \   cx = (ax,bx) $

The reader familiar with ideals will note that these equivalences are captured more concisely in the distributive law for ideal multiplication $\rm\:(a,b)(x) = (ax,bx),\:$ when interpreted in a PID or Bezout domain, where the ideal $\rm\:(a,b) = (c)\iff c = gcd(a,b)$

---

Alternatively, more generally, in *any* integral domain $\rm\:D\:$ we have

**Theorem** $\rm\ \ (a,b)\ =\ (ax,bx)/x\ \ $ if $\rm\ (ax,bx)\ $ exists in $\rm\:D.$

**Proof** $\rm\quad\: c\ |\ a,b \iff cx\ |\ ax,bx \iff cx\ |\ (ax,bx) \iff c\ |\ (ax,bx)/x$

The above proof uses the [*universal* definitions of GCD, LCM](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/if-a-m-and-a-1-m-prove-aa-1-m/3149#3149), which often serve to simplify proofs, e.g. see [this proof of the GCD * LCM law.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/upper-and-lower-bounds-of-emptyset/3832#3832)

---

Alternatively, comparing powers of primes in unique  factorizations, it reduces to the following
$$ \min(a+c,\,b+c)\ =\ \min(a,b) + c$$

The proof is *precisely* the same as the prior proof, replacing gcd by min, and divides by $\le$, and

$$\begin{eqnarray} {\rm employing}\quad\ c\le a,b&\iff& c\le \min(a,b),\\
\rm the\ analog\ of\quad\   c\  \, |\, \ a,b&\iff&\rm c\ \,|\,\ (a,b) \end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: why if $c = (a,b)$ then $c = ja + kb$ ?