# Proving that if $c = gcd(f,g)$ then $c = kf + mg$ and that $m,k$ are unique

Tags: linear-algebra

I had to prove this:

> $p \cdot gcd(f,g) = \gcd(pf,pg)$,    $p,f,g \in \mathbb F [x]$

Now I came to this, and had help and:

> $c = \gcd(f,g) \rightarrow \exists m,k \in \mathbb F : c = mf + k g \; : m,k \; \text{are unique}$

Then:

> $p \cdot c = pmf + pkg \rightarrow p \cdot \gcd(f,g) = \gcd(pf,pg)$

But what I do not understand is,
Why is $c = mf + kg$ and why is $pmf + pkg = \gcd(pf,pg)$?

Comment: You probably mean that $m$ and $k$ are in $\mathbb{F}[x]$. They are not unique.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by unique: $c=mf+kg=(m+rg)f+(k-rf)g$. In an ordered field one can use this to show, for example, that there is a unique form in which $0 \le m \lt g$

Comment: http://books.google.com.vn/books?id=s7T8ycRQjcgC&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=greatest+common+divisor+in+pid+existence+proof&source=bl&ots=ro_byO4a81&sig=2pDGvOOcPv7QZr4Y4B79LEBq6uA&hl=vi&sa=X&ei=YhaNUbPqN-eTiAest4GQCA&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=greatest%20common%20divisor%20in%20pid%20existence%20proof&f=false Page 49 of this book does provide a proof of the existence of gcd in a PID. Give it a shot, and ask if you still don't get it. And one thing to remember is $\mathbb{F}[x]$ is a PID for all field $F$. Btw, I don't really think that $m; k$ should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

That is because $\gcd(a,b)=k \implies a=h \cdot k$ and $b= f \cdot k$ and $\gcd(h,f)=1$(Why?)

Now, $ap=hkp$ and $bp=fkp \implies \gcd(ap,bp)=pk$

Here $a,b,k,h,f$ and $p$ are polynomials.

You have asked a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363501/prove-that-gcdpf-pg-p-cdot-gcdf-g-when-p-f-g-are-polynomials/363511#363511). And Mathgems answer does answer every bit of it.

Comment: Yes, because his answer does not answer every bit of it, and that's why I asked again!

Comment: $\gcd (x^2+1,x^2)=1$ You have  $x^2(-1)+(x^2+1)(1)=1$. What would multiplying any polynomial would give you?

Comment: What is truly bothering me is WHY if $c = mf + kg$ then $pc = pmf + pkg$ has to be the GCD? perhaps there is a bigger $pm, pk$ that satisfy this?

Comment: That's because there are **no** bigger divisor of both of them as you think.

Comment: thank you so much Inceptio

Comment: Inceptio. why is $gcd(h,f)=1$?

Comment: @TheNotMe: If its **not** $1$, you will not have $\gcd$ as $k$. Try out some examples you will see why.