# Prove that if $a$ and $bc$ are nonzero integers, then $(ca,cb) = |c|(a,b)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Prove that if *a* and *bc* are nonzero integers, then $$(ca,cb) = |c|(a,b).$$

Basically, I was confused by the statement of the question. In particular, I was unsure if choosing *a* and *bc* to be nonzero was arbitrary. In other words, why choose *a* and *bc* to be nonzero instead of just saying *"Prove that if a, b, and c are nonzero integers..."* or, as the person who provided a solution suggested, why not just say *"Prove if a, b, and c are integers with abc nonzero..."*

Comment: I'm not sure if there is some advantage to wording the question such that _a_ and _bc_ are given to be nonzero integers rather than, say, some other equivalent form to word the question, such as the examples I added to my posted question (after editing).

However, I think that is really where my question lies. I assumed there was some premeditation behind the wording such that it was intended to be a hint or something. For example, maybe that I was supposed to view _bc_ as a product for some particular reason.

But I guess the wording of the question was arbitrary?

Comment: There's no reason why it should be or has been written that way. A slightly stronger statement is that it is true if c is nonzero and a and b are not both 0 - perhaps they were trying to include that case and did it (very) wrongly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d = (ca, cb)$ and $d' = |c|(a,b)$.

By the property of gcd, $\exists x,y$ s.t. $d = cax + cby$. $\frac{d}{|c|(a,b)} = \frac{c}{|c|} \frac{a}{(a,b)} x + \frac{c}{|c|} \frac{b}{(a,b)} y$. Note that each fraction on the right is an integer since $|c|$ divides c and $(a,b)$ divides $a$ and $b$. Hence $d'|d$.

Now $d' = |c|(au+bv) = |c|au + |c|bv$ for some $u,v$ by the property of gcd. $(ca,cb)$ divides $|c|a$ and $|c|b$ so $d|d'$.

Since both $d$ and $d'$ are positive, $d = d'$ which is the required result.

Comment: Thanks. That is essentially the same solution I came up with, but wasn't sure because the statement of the problem confused me. I was thinking the problem would make more sense if it said let _a_ and _b_ be integers both not zero. Not sure why it says "_a_ and _bc_ are nonzero."

Comment: $c$ needs to be nonzero as well (unless we define the gcd of 0 to be trivially zero). $bc$ nonzero implies both $b$ and $c$ are both nonzero. So technically the question could have written the condition as the product $abc$ is nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

This is the fundamental gcd *distributive* law $\rm\:(ax,bx) = (a,b)x.\:$  It is instructive to prove it in various ways. here are $3$ proofs, using Bezout's identity,  universal gcd laws, unique factorization.

---

First we show that the gcd distributive law follows immediately from the fact that, by Bezout, the [gcd may be specified by linear equations.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112026/242) Distributivity follows because such linear equations are preserved by scalings. Namely, for naturals $\rm\:a,b,c,x \ne 0$

$\rm\qquad\qquad \phantom{ \iff }\ \ \ \:\! c = (a,b) $

$\rm\qquad\qquad \iff\ \: c\:\ |\ \:a,\:b\ \ \ \  \ \ \&\ \ \ \ c\ =\ na\: +\: kb,\ \  \ $ some $\rm\:n,k\in \mathbb Z$

$\rm\qquad\qquad \iff\  cx\ |\ ax,bx\ \ \ \&\ \ \ cx = nax + kbx,\ \,$ some $\rm\:n,k\in \mathbb Z$

$\rm\qquad\qquad { \iff }\ \   cx = (ax,bx) $

The reader familiar with ideals will note that these equivalences are captured more concisely in the distributive law for ideal multiplication $\rm\:(a,b)(x) = (ax,bx),\:$ when interpreted in a PID or Bezout domain, where the ideal $\rm\:(a,b) = (c)\iff c = gcd(a,b)$

---

Alternatively, more generally, in *any* integral domain $\rm\:D\:$ we may employ the [*universal* definitions of GCD, LCM](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/if-a-m-and-a-1-m-prove-aa-1-m/3149#3149) to generalize the above proof.

**Theorem** $\rm\ \ (a,b)\ =\ (ax,bx)/x\ \ $ if $\rm\ (ax,bx)\ $ exists in $\rm\:D.$

**Proof** $\rm\quad\: c\ |\ a,b \iff cx\ |\ ax,bx \iff cx\ |\ (ax,bx) \iff c\ |\ (ax,bx)/x\ \ \ $ **QED**

Such *universal* definitions often serve to simplify proofs, e.g. see [this proof of the GCD * LCM law.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/upper-and-lower-bounds-of-emptyset/3832#3832)

---

Alternatively, comparing powers of primes in unique  factorizations, it reduces to the following
$$ \min(a+c,\,b+c)\ =\ \min(a,b) + c$$

The proof is *precisely* the same as the prior proof, replacing gcd by min, and divides by $\le$, and

$$\begin{eqnarray} {\rm employing}\quad\ c\le a,b&\iff& c\le \min(a,b)\quad&&\rm[universal\  definition\ of\ \ min]\\
\rm the\ analog\ of\quad\   c\  \, |\, \ a,b&\iff&\rm c\ \ |\ \ gcd(a,b)\quad&&\rm[universal\  definition\ of\ \ gcd] \end{eqnarray}$$